# Form inside a table

Tags: html, firebug, html-table, forms

I'm including some forms inside a HTML table to add new rows and update current rows. The problem that I'm getting is that when I inspect the forms in my dev tools, I see that the form elements are closed immediately after opening (inputs, etc are not included within the form).

As such, submitting a form fails to include the fields.

The table row and inputs are as follows:

```
<tr>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="job_num">
        </td>

        <td>
            <input type="text" name="desc">
        </td>
    </form>
</tr>
```

Any help would be great, thank you.

Comment: `<form>` can not be put inside `<tr>`.

Comment: And you forgot to close the `<tr>`.

Comment: Use display:table-row for your form and ditch the table tag altogether. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15600151/1038812

Comment: It can't, but it works...

Answer (score 476, accepted):

A form is [not allowed](http://validator.w3.org/) to be a child element of a `table`, `tbody` or `tr`. Attempting to put one there will tend to cause the browser to move the form to it appears *after* the table (while leaving its contents — table rows, table cells, inputs, etc — behind).

You can have an entire table inside a form. You can have a form inside a table cell. You cannot have part of a table inside a form.

Use one form around the entire table. Then either use the clicked submit button to determine which row to process (to be quick) or process every row (allowing bulk updates).

HTML 5 introduces the [`form` *attribute*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#form). This allows you to provide one form per row **outside the table** and then associate all the form control in a given row with one of those forms using its `id`.

Comment: Take care using one form for the entire table, all fields will be send to server, even if they are empty. It could be a huge amount of data !!!
Please for mass/public usage, prefer to use a dialog (form not in table) opened from a button in that row.

Comment: @Loenix: It is very unlikely that you'll put enough data in the table for it to be a significant burden on people's bandwidth (at least when compared to the size of a typical webpage). Requiring users to load another page between choosing to edit a row and being able to make their changes, OTOH, would be an annoying extra interaction that they would have to perform.

Comment: I was not talking about opening another page but to use a dialog/modal. e.g http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-examples This allow you to use a more beautiful form, to get more inputs in an optimized way. When you display 100+ rows with 10 inputs each... it's getting much

Comment: It's still an extra interaction for the user (and negates the possibility of doing batch updates).

Comment: This is not really an extra interaction... You still need an edit button and a save button for both solution. It negates the possibility of doing batch updates but make your choice for quite substantial forms (> 3 fields), the inline form will be unusable and the user will not do batch updates. I don't tell you that you have to do this way but just dont forget to consider this problem. ;-)

Comment: You don't need an edit button for the solution proposed in the original question.

Comment: Why did the prohibited `<form>` inside of `<table>` in the standards?

Comment: @1234ru — I wouldn't want to speculate on the reasons that people made a design decision two decades ago.

Comment: @Qentin fair enough. It's a pity this still stands after two decades with no obvious reason.

Comment: @1234ru — It still stands because backwards compatibility is important

Comment: @GeneCode — No code sample could explain things as clearly as the first two sentences of the middle paragraph.

Answer (score 255):

Use the **"form" attribute**, if you want to save your markup:

```
<form method="GET" id="my_form"></form>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="company" form="my_form" />
            <button type="button" form="my_form">ok</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

(*Form fields outside of the < form > tag)

Comment: Note, this solution is only valid with HTML5.

Comment: moreover, it won't work in internet explorer [more info here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-attribute)

Comment: Is there any plan to make it IE compatible, do you know @SouhaiebBesbes? I can't get my form working any other way.

Comment: The status of form attribute is 'under consideration' which means you have to be very patient   https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/formattribute meanwhile you can try this polyfill and see if it works for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/26696165/648484

Comment: Seems "in development" now, and ok to use

Comment: @user1156544 It's supported in Edge now, but not IE. If you need to support IE at all, you're out of luck with this solution. My plan is to use two tables for two form elements (I can't believe I have to do this). Thanks Microsoft!

Comment: @Pluto This is the straw that's going to break the camel's back of IE 11 support at our company. It's six years old now. It's time for it to die.

Answer (score 60):

If you want a "editable grid" i.e. a table like structure that allows you to make any of the rows a form, use CSS that mimics the TABLE tag's layout: `display:table`, `display:table-row`, and `display:table-cell`.

There is no need to wrap your whole table in a form and no need to create a separate form and table for each apparent row of your table.

Try this instead:

```
<style>
DIV.table 
{
    display:table;
}
FORM.tr, DIV.tr
{
    display:table-row;
}
SPAN.td
{
    display:table-cell;
}
</style>
...
<div class="table">
    <form class="tr" method="post" action="blah.html">
        <span class="td"><input type="text"/></span>
        <span class="td"><input type="text"/></span>
    </form>
    <div class="tr">
        <span class="td">(cell data)</span>
        <span class="td">(cell data)</span>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

The problem with wrapping the whole TABLE in a FORM is that any and all form elements will be sent on submit (maybe that is desired but probably not). This method allows you to define a form for each "row" and send only that row of data on submit.

The problem with wrapping a FORM tag around a TR tag (or TR around a FORM) is that it's invalid HTML. The FORM will still allow submit as usual but at this point the DOM is broken. Note: Try getting the child elements of your FORM or TR with JavaScript, it can lead to unexpected results.

Note that IE7 doesn't support these CSS table styles and IE8 will need a doctype declaration to get it into "standards" mode: (try this one or something equivalent)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Any other browser that supports display:table, display:table-row and display:table-cell should display your css data table the same as it would if you were using the TABLE, TR and TD tags. Most of them do.

Note that you can also mimic THEAD, TBODY, TFOOT by wrapping your row groups in another DIV with `display: table-header-group`, `table-row-group` and `table-footer-group` respectively.

**NOTE:** The only thing you cannot do with this method is colspan.

Check out this illustration: http://jsfiddle.net/ZRQPP/

Comment: +1 for mentioning this does not enable colspan... which I must have missed the first reading it through ;-)

Comment: That should be the green checked answer (even if don't use really table tag)

Comment: " Note: Try getting the child elements of your FORM or TR with JavaScript, it can lead to unexpected results." That´s exactly how I learned it despite this being a very old post. Who pays the "define standards" guys? I wan´t a word with them

Answer (score 0):

Even though, as [Quentin mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5967613/10843739), it is not allowed to put a form inside a table. We can workaround this limitation with slots which are used in web components.

First of all we need to create a template of our table in our HTML file:

```
<template id="my-table">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>first column</td>
      <td>second column <slot name="my-form"></slot></td>
      <td>third column</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</template>
```

The slot element is an insertion point, elements with attribute `slot="my-form"` will be rendered inside of it.

Then we define a custom component in JS:

```
customElements.define(
  "my-table",
  class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
      let template = document.getElementById("my-table");
      let templateContent = template.content;

      const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
      shadowRoot.appendChild(templateContent.cloneNode(true));
    }
  }
);
```

In order to use slots we need to use shadow DOM, that's why we attach a shadow root to the custom element, it contains the content of the template.

Now we can go back to the HTML file and use the custom table component

```
<my-table>
  <form action="" slot="my-form">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="" />
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
</my-table>
```

The above form element references the named slot `"my-form"`, therefore it will be placed inside of it.

This workaround works because the form element isn't explicitly placed inside the table. The form is simply rendered inside the slot element as shown here:

[image: DOM structure]