# CakePHP, Form Helper Tag Issue With Pageinated Results

Tags: jquery, forms, cakephp

what I need is someone to see why CakePHP (Ver 2.2.2) is doing what it is doing? OK the breakdown of my code is as follows. The DIV PageList is a JQuery Accordion, with two drop downs, one for an admin to add a new use and the other to view all users and make some changes. Add user is fine and works without any problems.

My problem is (or at lest i think it is) withe the Form Helper, I did have the Form Create call outside my foreach loop before and was working without any problems, I would find the user I wanted to change something on and then save, no problem. When I stated to pageinate the results I started to get problems. As when the Form Create was outside the foreach and just before the start of my table code, only the last results displayed would be able to save the changes made. I found the cause of the problem and that was the ID field was always defaulting to last displayed result. so I moved the Form Create to within my foreach loop.

This now works but for some reason, it starts the ends right away, therefore my inputs are now seating outside the form tags? I don't understand why because I have the end Form Helper end() call at the bottom of the foreach loop. Therefore it should just display each user in its own form.

I am not sure if this is a issue and can still use it like this. But the one issue is that my form now starts after my table, which will not validate with W3C, this is not a big issue. Side note, is it ok to use tables still? I am listing data with them? I am trying to learn the HTML 5 spec. but have not really seen anything about tables let...

Many Thanks. Glenn Curtis.

```
echo '<div id="PageList">';

$OutputHolder = '<h3 class="Background-Titles">Add User</h3>';
$OutputHolder .= '<div class="Background-Content" id="AdminAddUser">';
$OutputHolder .=  $this->Form->create('User', array('url'=>'http://glenns-showcase.net/projects/cake/DrWho/adminadd/', 'inputDefaults' => array('div' => false) ) ); 
$OutputHolder .=  $this->Form->input('username');
$OutputHolder .=  $this->Form->input('password');
$OutputHolder .=  $this->Form->input('firstname');
$OutputHolder .=  $this->Form->input('surname');
$OutputHolder .=  $this->Form->input('email');
$OutputHolder .= 'Select Role For User <br />';
$OutputHolder .=  $this->Form->radio('role_id', $opt_role, $attributes);
$OutputHolder .= '<br />Select Active State For User <br />';
$OutputHolder .=  $this->Form->radio('active', $opt_active, $attributes);
$OutputHolder .=  $this->Form->end('Submit'); 
$OutputHolder .= '</div>'; //End for AddUser
echo $OutputHolder;

$OutputViewUsers = '<h3 class="Background-Titles">View All Users</h3>';
$OutputViewUsers .= '<div class="Background-Content" id="AdminViewUsers">';

$OutputViewUsers .=  '<table border="0">';
$OutputViewUsers .=  '<tr><td>Username</td><td>First Name</td><td>Surname</td><td>E-mail</td><td>Stutus</td><td>Level</td><td>Save</td></tr>';
foreach($users as $key => $value) {
    $OutputViewUsers .= $this->Form->create('UserEdit', array('url'=>'http://glenns-showcase.net/projects/cake/DrWho/adminedit/', 'inputDefaults' => array('div' => false) ) );
    $BaseLink = $users[$key]['User']; 
    $OutputViewUsers .= "<td class=\"AdminViewUsersUN\">" .($BaseLink  ['username']) . "</td>";
    $OutputViewUsers .= "<td>" . $this->Form->input('fname', array('default' => $BaseLink  ['firstname'], 'label' => false,  'class' => 'AdminViewUsersFN') ) . "</td>";
    $OutputViewUsers .= "<td>" . $this->Form->input('sname', array('default' => $BaseLink  ['surname'], 'label' => false,  'class' => 'AdminViewUsersSN') ). "</td>";
    $OutputViewUsers .= "<td>" . $this->Form->input('email', array('default' => $BaseLink  ['email'], 'label' => false,  'class' => 'AdminViewUsersEM') ). "</td>";
    $OutputViewUsers .= "<td>" . $this->Form->select('active', $ActOpts, array('empty' => false, 'default' => $BaseLink  ['active'], 'class' => 'AdminViewUsersAS') ). "</td>";
    $OutputViewUsers .= "<td>" . $this->Form->select('role', $RoleOpts, array('empty' => false, 'default' => $users[$key]['Role']['id'],  'class' => 'AdminViewUsersUL') ). "</td>";
    $OutputViewUsers .= $this->Form->hidden('id', array('default' => $BaseLink  ['id'], ) );
    $OutputViewUsers .= "<td>" . $this->Form->submit('Save', array('div' => false, 'class' => 'AdminViewUsersSB') ). "</td></tr>"; 
    //$test = array('label' => 'Save', 'div' => array('class' => 'AdminViewUsersSB'));
    $OutputViewUsers .=  $this->Form->end(); 

} //End of foreach loop
$OutputViewUsers .= '</table>';

$OutputViewUsers .= $this->Paginator->numbers(array('first' => 2));
$OutputViewUsers .= '</div>'; //End for AllUsers 
echo $OutputViewUsers;

echo '</div>'; //End for PageList
```

UPDATE :::

This is how it looks now! But this now, is more or lest how I had it before. I have added the missing  tag. But this now only lets the last result work! I paginate for 5 results per page, and the top four results on the page will not work because they have the wrong ID number, each time any 'save' is pushed, only the id from the last result is supplied.

I am not sure what your mean by "index the input the input fields" but with "give the submit elements unique names containing the appropriate index of the associated records" as far as I was aware I was doing that, which having a hidden field that supplies the ID.

What I looks like to me is that I have to put the whole form within my loop, so that each returned result is in its own form, then there should be no error! However I cant put the start of my table within in the loop or I have a header for each result! I think I should be able to work around this issue!

Many Thanks for your help!

```
$OutputViewUsers = '<h3 class="Background-Titles">View All Users</h3>';
$OutputViewUsers .= '<div class="Background-Content" id="AdminViewUsers">';
$OutputViewUsers .= $this->Form->create('UserEdit', array('url'=>'http://glenns-showcase.net/projects/cake/DrWho/adminedit/', 'inputDefaults' => array('div' => false) ) );
$OutputViewUsers .=  '<table border="0">';
$OutputViewUsers .=  '<tr><td>Username</td><td>First Name</td><td>Surname</td><td>E-mail</td><td>Stutus</td><td>Level</td><td>Save</td></tr>';
foreach($users as $key => $value) {
    $BaseLink = $users[$key]['User']; 
    $OutputViewUsers .= "<tr><td class=\"AdminViewUsersUN\">" .($BaseLink  ['username']) . "</td>";
    $OutputViewUsers .= "<td>" . $this->Form->input('fname', array('default' => $BaseLink  ['firstname'], 'label' => false,  'class' => 'AdminViewUsersFN') ) . "</td>";
    $OutputViewUsers .= "<td>" . $this->Form->input('sname', array('default' => $BaseLink  ['surname'], 'label' => false,  'class' => 'AdminViewUsersSN') ). "</td>";
    $OutputViewUsers .= "<td>" . $this->Form->input('email', array('default' => $BaseLink  ['email'], 'label' => false,  'class' => 'AdminViewUsersEM') ). "</td>";
    $OutputViewUsers .= "<td>" . $this->Form->select('active', $ActOpts, array('empty' => false, 'default' => $BaseLink  ['active'], 'class' => 'AdminViewUsersAS') ). "</td>";
    $OutputViewUsers .= "<td>" . $this->Form->select('role', $RoleOpts, array('empty' => false, 'default' => $users[$key]['Role']['id'],  'class' => 'AdminViewUsersUL') ). "</td>";
    $OutputViewUsers .= $this->Form->hidden('id', array('default' => $BaseLink  ['id'], ) );
    $OutputViewUsers .= "<td>" . $this->Form->submit('Save', array('div' => false, 'class' => 'AdminViewUsersSB') ). "</td></tr>"; 
} //End of foreach loop
$OutputViewUsers .= '</table>';
$OutputViewUsers .=  $this->Form->end(); 
$OutputViewUsers .= $this->Paginator->numbers(array('first' => 2));
$OutputViewUsers .= '</div>'; //End for AllUsers 
echo $OutputViewUsers;
```

ANOTHER UPDATE ::

This now seems to work, each result is in its own form elements and all the inputs or now within the form tags. However, each result now has its own header, because I now have the table inside the form but that is now within my foreach loop, so each time it loops, it echos/prints the headers at the top of the result. I be working on this. Any help is still most welcome!!

```
foreach($users as $key => $value) {
    $OutputViewUsers .= $this->Form->create('UserEdit', array('url'=>'http://glenns-showcase.net/projects/cake/DrWho/adminedit/', 'inputDefaults' => array('div' => false) ) );
    $OutputViewUsers .=  '<table border="0">';
    $OutputViewUsers .=  '<tr><td>Username</td><td>First Name</td><td>Surname</td><td>E-mail</td><td>Stutus</td><td>Level</td><td>Save</td></tr>';
    $BaseLink = $users[$key]['User']; 
    $OutputViewUsers .= "<tr><td class=\"AdminViewUsersUN\">" .($BaseLink  ['username']) . "</td>";
    $OutputViewUsers .= "<td>" . $this->Form->input('fname', array('default' => $BaseLink  ['firstname'], 'label' => false,  'class' => 'AdminViewUsersFN') ) . "</td>";
    $OutputViewUsers .= "<td>" . $this->Form->input('sname', array('default' => $BaseLink  ['surname'], 'label' => false,  'class' => 'AdminViewUsersSN') ). "</td>";
    $OutputViewUsers .= "<td>" . $this->Form->input('email', array('default' => $BaseLink  ['email'], 'label' => false,  'class' => 'AdminViewUsersEM') ). "</td>";
    $OutputViewUsers .= "<td>" . $this->Form->select('active', $ActOpts, array('empty' => false, 'default' => $BaseLink  ['active'], 'class' => 'AdminViewUsersAS') ). "</td>";
    $OutputViewUsers .= "<td>" . $this->Form->select('role', $RoleOpts, array('empty' => false, 'default' => $users[$key]['Role']['id'],  'class' => 'AdminViewUsersUL') ). "</td>";
    $OutputViewUsers .= $this->Form->hidden('id', array('default' => $BaseLink  ['id'], ) );
    $OutputViewUsers .= "<td>" . $this->Form->submit('Save', array('div' => false, 'class' => 'AdminViewUsersSB') ). "</td></tr>"; 
    //$test = array('label' => 'Save', 'div' => array('class' => 'AdminViewUsersSB'));
    $OutputViewUsers .= '</table>';
    $OutputViewUsers .=  $this->Form->end(); 

} //End of foreach loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply generating invalid HTML. You are missing an opening `tr` tag in the loop, but even if it were present it would be still invalid, because [`tr` is only allowed to hold `td` or `th` elements](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/tabular-data.html#the-tr-element), so the browser might render the forms outside of the table.

See also [Form inside a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967564/form-inside-a-table)

One workaround would be to wrap the whole table inside the form, index the input the input fields, give the submit elements unique names containing the appropriate index of the associated records, and use this name on the serverside to determine which record to save. Or compare the submitted data with the database and save only the records where something was changed.

ps. yes, tables are fine as long as they are used for what they are intended, for describing tabular data.

Answer (score 0):

I have marked the above as the answer as it set me on the right track, so many thanks!

I now have the form inside my loop and the table inside the form. This now means each result is in its own form tags.

With the headers I have just used CSS and span tags to line them up!

Many thanks Glenn.

Here is my final code, just in case any one else finds this of any use.

```
$OutputViewUsers = '<h3 class="Background-Titles">View All Users</h3>';
$OutputViewUsers .= '<div class="Background-Content" id="AdminViewUsers">';
$OutputViewUsers .=  '<div class="AdminViewUsersListHeaders">
    <span class="AdminViewUsersUNHeader">Username</span>
    <span class="AdminViewUsersFNHeader">First Name</span>
    <span class="AdminViewUsersSNHeader">Surname</span>
    <span class="AdminViewUsersEMHeader">E-mail</span>
    <span class="AdminViewUsersASHeader">Stutus</span>
    <span class="AdminViewUsersULHeader">Level</span>
    <span class="AdminViewUsersSAHeader">Save</span></div>';


foreach($users as $key => $value) {
    $OutputViewUsers .= $this->Form->create('UserEdit', array('url'=>'http://glenns-showcase.net/projects/cake/DrWho/adminedit/', 'inputDefaults' => array('div' => false) ) );
    $OutputViewUsers .=  '<table border="0">';
    //$OutputViewUsers .=  '<tr><td>Username</td><td>First Name</td><td>Surname</td><td>E-mail</td><td>Stutus</td><td>Level</td><td>Save</td></tr>';
    $BaseLink = $users[$key]['User']; 
    $OutputViewUsers .= "<tr><td class=\"AdminViewUsersUN\">" .($BaseLink  ['username']) . "</td>";
    $OutputViewUsers .= "<td>" . $this->Form->input('fname', array('default' => $BaseLink  ['firstname'], 'label' => false,  'class' => 'AdminViewUsersFN') ) . "</td>";
    $OutputViewUsers .= "<td>" . $this->Form->input('sname', array('default' => $BaseLink  ['surname'], 'label' => false,  'class' => 'AdminViewUsersSN') ). "</td>";
    $OutputViewUsers .= "<td>" . $this->Form->input('email', array('default' => $BaseLink  ['email'], 'label' => false,  'class' => 'AdminViewUsersEM') ). "</td>";
    $OutputViewUsers .= "<td>" . $this->Form->select('active', $ActOpts, array('empty' => false, 'default' => $BaseLink  ['active'], 'class' => 'AdminViewUsersAS') ). "</td>";
    $OutputViewUsers .= "<td>" . $this->Form->select('role', $RoleOpts, array('empty' => false, 'default' => $users[$key]['Role']['id'],  'class' => 'AdminViewUsersUL') ). "</td>";
    $OutputViewUsers .= $this->Form->hidden('id', array('default' => $BaseLink  ['id'], ) );
    $OutputViewUsers .= "<td>" . $this->Form->submit('Save', array('div' => false, 'class' => 'AdminViewUsersSB') ). "</td></tr>"; 
    //$test = array('label' => 'Save', 'div' => array('class' => 'AdminViewUsersSB'));
    $OutputViewUsers .= '</table>';
    $OutputViewUsers .=  $this->Form->end(); 

} //End of foreach loop


$OutputViewUsers .= $this->Paginator->numbers(array('first' => 2));
$OutputViewUsers .= '</div>'; //End for AllUsers 
echo $OutputViewUsers;
```