# Firefox does not submit my form

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, firefox

I have a php application that fetches the requests from mysql database and displays them for further approval. The form is fetched from `send_req.php` and is displayed inside the div on `showrequests.php`. This is the code for `send_req.php`

```
<table style="border:0;border-color:transparent">
<tr style="background-color:lightblue">
<td>Product ID</td>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Quantity</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="selectAll" /></td>
<td>Authorized Quantity</td>
</tr>
<form method="post" action="send_req.php">
<?php
$reqNum = $_POST['rId'];
echo "<h3>Request # $reqNum</h3>";

$showReqs = mysql_query("Select * from request where request_number='".$reqNum."' and status=0");
    while($resultA = mysql_fetch_array($showReqs))
    {
        $rBy = $resultA['requested_by'];
        $rTime = $resultA['request_time'];
        $rId = $resultA['id'];
        $pId = $resultA['product_id'];
        $getPrName = mysql_query("select name from products where id='$pId'");
        $prN = mysql_fetch_array($getPrName);
        $prName = $prN['name'];
        $rQuantity = $resultA['requested_quantity'];
        $status = $resultA['status'];

?>
    <tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="rId[]" value="<?php echo $rId; ?>"/>
    <td style="background-color:orange"><input type="text" name="prId[]" value="<?php echo $pId; ?>" readonly="readonly" style="border:0px"/></td>
    <td style="background-color:orange"><input type="text" name="prName[]" value="<?php echo $prName; ?>" readonly="readonly" style="border:0px"/></td>
    <td style="background-color:orange"><input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="<?php echo $rQuantity; ?>" readonly="readonly" style="border:0px"/></td>
    <td style="background-color:orange"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="pQuantity[]" /></td>
    </tr>
<?php }
?>
    <tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<input type="hidden" name="rNum" value="<?php echo $reqNum; ?>" />
<td></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submitReq" value="Send" id="submit_req" style="backgroundColor:Transparent;border:0;color:blue;width:100;"/></td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
<?php
echo "Requested By:$rBy at ".substr($rTime,11,18)." ".substr($rTime,0,10);
?>
```

This is the `showrequests.php` page

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getRequest(ob)
{
    var id = ob.id;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    ajaxOb = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else if(window.ActiveXObject)
{
    ajaxOb = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}  
     ajaxOb.open("POST", "send_req.php");   
     ajaxOb.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");                    
     ajaxOb.send("rId=" + id);  
     ajaxOb.onreadystatechange = function()  
    {  
        if(ajaxOb.readyState == 4)
        {
            if(ajaxOb.status == 200)
            {
                document.getElementById("showTable").innerHTML = ajaxOb.responseText;
            }
        }

    }  
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$mysql_con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Could not connect ".mysql_error());
$mysql_db = mysql_select_db("cart",$mysql_con) or die("Unable to select db ".mysql_error());
echo "<h2 align='center'>Pending Requests</h2>";
$showReq = mysql_query("Select distinct(request_number) as rNums from request where status=0");
?>
<div style="float:left;margin-right:15px;">
<br/>
<?php
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($showReq))
{
    $rNum = $result['rNums'];
?>
<input type="button" name="fetchReq" id="<?php echo $rNum; ?>" value="<?php echo "Request # $rNum"; ?>" style="margin-bottom:5px;backgroundColor:Transparent;border:0;color:blue;width:100;text-Decoration:underline" onclick="getRequest(this)"/>

<?php
    echo "<br/>";
}
?>
</div>
<div id="showTable" style="float: left">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My problem now is that everything works fine in chrome and IE but the form is not submitted when i click the submit button in firefox. I am using firefox 20.0.1. Update: I have removed the `html,head and body` tags from `send_req.php`
still not working

Comment: Please read the FAQ section of this site carefully. It clearly advises you to post _only the relevant bits of code_, all info that might be relevant to the question (as in: check your console if FF), and shows some effort of your own as to what is causing the problem. Also: stop using `mysql_*` in php, as it is deprecated

Comment: you are probably using very very very old firefox. try to update it to that latest release and check again. I do not see any error in your ode

Comment: If this is a public form, you have a rather big issue. You are not sanitizing your input before feeding it into your sql query, which leaves it wide open for a sql injection hack.

Comment: Clean up your code and only show relevant parts, I cannot find your opening `<form>` line to save my life (if you feel it necessary to show the entire thing, link a paste bin, but please, just show relevant parts

Comment: If an answer did fix you problem, please mark it as accepted for future visitors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

form is not allowed inside table. Please see also 
[Form inside a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967564/form-inside-a-table)

Regards,
Michael

Comment: well what do you know. i put the table inside the form and it works. Also i fixed the html issues as well. put the div inside the body. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Reminder : the structure of an HTML document is :

```
<!-- No div before html tag -->
    <!DOCTYPE html> <!-- Doctype for HTML5 ; use whatever doctype you need -->
    <html>
        <head>

        </head>

        <!-- No div before body tag -->
        <body>
             <!-- Divs only belongs here -->
        </body>    
    </html>
<!-- No div after html tag -->
```

If you don't follow this basic structure, you're forcing the browser to interpret your invalid code (+ quirks mode when you don't provide a doctype).

Some browser guess well what you tried to do, others don't, as Firefox might.

Please use a HTML validator as [W3's validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to check your syntax.

Comment: I fixed the issues you pointed out. Also, i put the table inside the form tag. thank you for helping