# using Html.BeginForm putting content after the closing </form> tag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So I have a partial view inside which I am creating a form

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("UpdateTimesheet", "Entry", FormMethod.Post, new { id = @i }))
{
    <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.TimeEntry.LocationId, Model.LocationList, "Please select a location")</td>
    <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.TimeEntry.Equipment.Code, Model.EquipmentList, "Please select equipment")</td>
    <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.TimeEntry.Staff.PayrollId, Model.StaffList, "Please select staff")</td>
    <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.TimeEntry.Task.Name, Model.TaskList, "Please select a task")</td>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.TimeEntry.LengthOfTime)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.TimeEntry.EventDateTime)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.TimeEntry.ReceivedDateTime)</td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "DisplayTimesheet", new { id = Model.TimeEntry.Id }, new { @class = "edit" })
        | 
        <a style="cursor: pointer" onclick="submitEdit(@i);">Save</a>
    </td>
}
```

But the HTML being rendered has the form closing immediately, followed by the html inside the curly braces. For example:

```
<form action="/Entry/UpdateTimesheet" id="edit1" method="post"></form>
<td>
    <select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field LocationId must be a number." id="TimeEntry_LocationId" name="TimeEntry.LocationId">
        <option value="">Please select a location</option>
        <option value="1">Location 1</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="3">Location 1</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

and so on. This partial view is being inserted into a table row ()

Any ideas why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: Which tag are you inserting your partial into? Is it a `<tr>`? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967564/form-inside-a-table

Comment: Yup, its a <tr>... sounds like thats the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might have something to do with you trying to put a form over a td tag, which basically puts the form right in the tr; which is not correct. You should try to put the form inside the td instead of outside.

Comment: Yeah, it is caused by trying to render the form directly inside the tr tag. I'll have to rethink my approach to avoid this

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to include an '@' in the BeginForm parameters.

`@using(Html.BeginForm("UpdateTimesheet", "Entry", FormMethod.Post, new { id = i }))` will work fine.

Comment: That may be so, but has nothing to do with the OP's reported problem.