# Parsley.js strange behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsley.js

I am building a registration form using parsley and I found that this code works:

```
<form  data-validate="parsley" id="registration_form" action="register.php" method="POST">

  <label>Full name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="full_name" name="full_name" placeholder="FirstName LastName" data-required="true" data-trigger="keyup" 
 data-regexp="^[A-Za-z ]+$" autofocus="autofocus">


  <label>Email address:</label>
  <input type="email" id="email_addr" name="email_addr" data-required="true" data-type="email" data-trigger="keyup">
```

But when I put it into table, even a small part of it, it fails to work.

```
    <table>
<tr><td>
<form  data-validate="parsley" id="registration_form" action="register.php" method="POST">

  <label>Full name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="full_name" name="full_name" placeholder="FirstName LastName" data-required="true" data-trigger="keyup" 
 data-regexp="^[A-Za-z ]+$" autofocus="autofocus">
</td></tr></table>
```

No errors from browser.

But what I find out is that if I am doing:

```
<form  data-validate="parsley" id="registration_form" action="register.php" method="POST">
```

before `<table>`, it work. However if I insert it (`<form ...>`) inside `<td></td>`, it fails.

As far as I know `<form>` tag is opened until `</form>` tag is given or until the end of document.
Is it terminated asap parent tag is terminated?
Can you explain what is my error?

Comment: Yes, i think the problem is your markup is not properly formed if the `<form>`'s parent `<td>` tag is closed before the `</form>`

Comment: Could you post an example on jsfiddle or pastebin please ?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967564/form-inside-a-table . Actually, I have used a form inside a table with parsley, so it can work. I'm guessing that your HTML has some issue.