# Access Table Last Row Value from input field javascript, Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

hello i have this table structure mentioned below

```
<table id="dataTable" class="center">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Location</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Latitiude</th>
      <th>Longitude</th>
      <th>Time Stamp</th><th >Status</th>
      <th></th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="saved">
      <td>10</td>
      <td>Sydney Yatch</td>
      <td>Yatch</td>
      <td>-33.848791</td>
      <td>151.218052</td>
      <td>2013-09-19 23:42:20</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="status" name="isSaved" value="1" /></td>
      <td><a href=db.php?action=delete&id=10>Delete</a> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="saved">
      <td>11</td>
      <td>Millers Point</td>
      <td>Point</td>
      <td>-33.858627</td>
      <td>151.204491</td>
      <td>2013-09-19 23:44:19</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="status" name="isSaved" value="1" /></td>
      <td><a href=db.php?action=delete&id=11>Delete</a> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="saved">
      <td>12</td>
      <td>Kot Pindi Das</td>
      <td>Restraunt</td>
      <td>31.740665</td>
      <td>74.230499</td>
      <td>2013-09-19 23:46:35</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="status" name="isSaved" value="1" /></td>
      <td><a href=db.php?action=delete&id=12>Delete</a> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="saved">
      <td>13</td>
      <td>Connto</td>
      <td>Island</td>
      <td>-33.848007</td>
      <td>151.171618</td>
      <td>2013-09-20 21:23:18</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="status" name="isSaved" value="1" /></td>
      <td><a href=db.php?action=delete&id=13>Delete</a> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="unSaved">
      <form method="get" action="db.php" ><td><input type="text" name="id" readonly value="15"/></td>
        <td> <input type="text" id="location" name="location" placeholder="Enter Location" /> </td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="type" placeholder="Enter Type" /> </td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="lat" readonly id="lat" /> </td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="long" readonly id="long" /> </td>
        <td>2013-09-21 17:35:14</td>
        <td ><input  type="text" id="status" name="isSaved" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Update" name="action" /></td>
      </form>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

now what i want is to access the value from textbox of the last row with id=isSaved
by using jquery or javascript

Comment: id of an element must be unique in a document, you have multiple elements with the same id `saved` also the id `isSaved` is missing

Comment: There's no textbox with `id="isSaved"`. Only `name="isSaved"`, is that what you meant?

Comment: There's also multiple `id="status"`.

Comment: Another problem: You can't have `<form>` as a child of `<tr>`. The children of `<tr>` must be either `<td>` or `<th>`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967564/form-inside-a-table

Comment: the functionality i want is when user right click on a page it takes the coordinates and if there is a row at the end of the table whose status is not saved then the values are copied into boxes,, values are being copied but when there is no row at the bottom to fill i want to display a dialog..

Comment: $("#lat").val(lat);
            $("#long").val(lang);
   
   var newRow = $("#dataTable > tr.unSaved").first(); //this is working fine 
   alert(newRow.find(".status").val()); // unable to get values 
   if(!newRow)// if never become true
   {
    $("#inputForm").dialog("open");
   }
   else// always lend here
   {
    newRow.find("#lat").val(lat);//works
    
    newRow.find("#long").val(lang);//works
    newRow.find("#location").focus();//works
   }

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jquery and have an id its as easy as

```
var val = $('#isSaved').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name=isSaved]').last().val();
```

If in doubt, check the Jquery website for documentation

Answer (score 0):

I recommend:

```
var myValue = $('#dataTable input:last-child').val();
```

Comment: what i want to achieve is when user click on update on any row it post only data of that row to another page..

Comment: what i want to achieve is when user click on update on any row it post only data of that row to another page..