# Turbolinks won't let me submit form without reloading page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I am using bootstrap 3 with turbolinks and the problem is, when I press on Submit button  in my edit form nothing happens, but if I reload page every input submits just fine. I don't understand why this happens, I'm not even using javascript in my form. Here is the code:

```
<div class = "row">
  <%= semantic_form_for @post do |f| %>
  <%= f.semantic_errors %>
  <div class = "form-group">
    <div class = "col-lg-9 col-md-7">   
      <%= f.input :title, :label => "Title" %>
      <%= f.input :content, :as => :rich, :allow_embeds => true %>
      <%= f.input :cat_list, :label => "Type your tags here" %>
    </div>
  <div class = "col-lg-3 col-md-4 ">
      <p>
      <%= image_tag(@post.thumbnail.url(:original), :class => "img-thumbnail") %>
      </p>
      <p>
      <%= f.input :thumbnail, as: :file %>
      </p>
      <p>
      <%= f.select :tag_list, Post::Tags, { }, { :multiple => true, :size => 10, :class => "form-control" } %>
      </p>
    </div>
  <%= f.action :submit, :as => :button, :button_html => { :class => "btn btn-primary" } %>
</div>
  <% end %>
<%= link_to 'Show', @post %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>
```

This is the content of my application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: There may be javascript at work in the form of Unobstrusive Javascript.  You may want to check on that.  http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript?view=asciicast

You also may want to ensure you're loading your javascript assets in the correct order, could you post the top part of your application.js here for us to see?

Comment: I've added application.js content to question

Comment: I am not sure if ERB looks at indentation, but if it does, your submit button does not lie nested under the semantic form declaration. Also please describe your version of Rails

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem: whenever arriving at a page using `link_to`, I had to refresh.

Add `data-no-turbolink="true"` inside your view's body tag.

Was solved by looking at [Form Submit button only works after reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365809/form-submit-button-only-works-after-reload).

Answer (score 1):

my experience with turbolinks is that it's much better to always add a listener to the submit form button like:

```
$('document').on 'click', '.submit-btn', ->
    $('form').submit()
```

the reason is because some JS/UJS have conflicts with turbolinks specially the one's with $('document').ready()  function because turbolinks does not refreshes the JS in the head, it only replaces the body.

if you have $('document').ready, you could replace it with turbolinks custom listeners (there are several others)

```
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by using `data: { turbolinks: false }` in the page that links to the page with the form, like so:

`<%= link_to "Get in Touch", 'contact', data: { turbolinks: false } %>`

Now the form works perfectly every time (without any page reload)