# Get checked status of checkbox in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

i have a form in my index-view where i create multiple checkboxes. One checkbox for every entry. This looks like this:

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for :user, url: usersupdate_path() do |f| %>
    <%= render @users %>
    <%= f.submit 'test', :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

**_user.html.erb**

```
<%= check_box_tag "checked[#{user.id}]","#{user.id}",true %>
```

**Description:**
With the form i want to allow the admin to uncheck users - this users i want to send to the controller and update their attributes.

There are only 2 problems:

**1)** I have to refresh the site until i can send the form to the controller - i don't know why

**2)** When i print the array it looks like this:

```
{"1"=>"1", "2"=>"2", "4"=>"4"}
```

User 3 was unchecked by me.

What i want is something like this:

```
{"1"=>"true", "2"=>"true", "3"=>"false", "4"=>"true"}
```

But how can i send the `checked` value of the checkbox to the controller?

In my controller i do only this at the moment:

```
def update
    flash[:success] = params[:checked]
    redirect_to root_path
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The browser does not serialize an unchecked checkbox when sending form data, so if it is not checked, it never gets sent.

You can generally fix this two ways. Make your action smart enough to see "missing" values as "unchecked", or add a hidden field before each checkbox:

```
 <%= hidden_field_tag "checked[#{user.id}]", "false" %>
 <%= check_box_tag "checked[#{user.id}]","#{user.id}", true %>
```

As for the true-values, the second parameter to `check_box_tag` is the value you want the checkbox to have, so you can change it to this:

```
 <%= hidden_field_tag "checked[#{user.id}]", "false" %>
 <%= check_box_tag "checked[#{user.id}]","true", true %>
```

And it should do what you want.

Note that if you use [`FormBuilder`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-check_box)s they handle this nuance for you.

Comment: Thanks! That is what i was looking for. An answer for the 1) question i found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19380727/3623608). The problem was that my form was inside a `<table>`-Tag. This doesn't work.