# Rails form not submitting if page loaded via link from other page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using rails 4.2.0.

**View:** `users/edit.html.erb` view is used for account settings form hitting the users controller/model. Devise is being used in the app, but the `devise/registrations.edit.html.erb` view is being used as a change password form.

If I navigate to my account settings page via its URL /users/:id/edit and make an edit, the form submits fine and updates attributes properly.

**Issue:**

The form does not submit if you arrive to the page from a link.

1. I click on the "Account Settings" link from a separate page, `<%= link_to "Account settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %>`
2. `users/edit.html.erb` view loads
3. Make and edit to an attribute on the users/edit view
4. Click submit button
5. Form does not submit, no POST is sent, button is unresponsive.

**Relative routes:**

```
           edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)  users#edit
                user GET    /users/:id(.:format)       users#show
                     PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)       users#update
                     PUT    /users/:id(.:format)       users#update
```

**Possibilities:**

I have never seen this happen before. Any help/ideas on a solutions, or how to better debug?

**EDIT1:**

`users/edit.html.erb` view:

```
<% provide(:title, "Account Settings") %>

<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 columns">
    <h2>Account settings</h2>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
  <div class="small-3 columns">
    <%= gravatar_for(@user, :size => 500) %>
    <%= link_to "Upload", "#", :class => "button tiny expand" %>
  </div>
  <div class="small-8 columns small-offset-1">
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :first_name %>
      <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :last_name %>
      <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :profile_description %>
      <%= f.text_field :profile_description %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="small-1 columns settings-icons-container">
    <%= image_tag 'icons/facebook.png', class: 'social-settings-icons' %>
    <%= image_tag 'icons/twitter.png', class: 'social-settings-icons' %>
    <%= image_tag 'icons/google-plus.png', class: 'social-settings-icons' %>
  </div>
  <div class="small-4 small-pull-7 columns">
    <h5>Social media links</h5>
    <!-- REPLACE WITH ERB -->
    <input type="text" for="facebook">
    <input type="text" for="twitter">
    <input type="text" for="website">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="small-3 columns">
    <%= link_to "Change password", edit_user_registration_path, :class => "button tiny expand radius" %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="small-3 columns actions ">
    <%= f.submit "Save changes", :class => "button expand radius small-3 columns" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you add some of your users/edit.html.erb? It sounds like there could be an issue with the HTML in the form.

Comment: please post your edit form code

Comment: did you figure out the answer to this? i'm having what i think is the same issue: if i refresh the page with form or access it directly through browser, it submits; if i arrive at form from a link, it doesn't submit.

Comment: Hey @TaylorT, Sorry for the late response. I marked your answer as correct, nice find and thanks for answering!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem: whenever arriving at a page using `link_to`, I had to refresh for the form to submit.

I fixed this by adding `data-no-turbolink="true"` inside `application.html.erb` view's body tag.

Was solved by looking at [Form Submit button only works after reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365809/form-submit-button-only-works-after-reload).

Comment: This is an old question but happened to me today and for those of you googling and getting here - disabling turbo links is a patch, not a fix. What fixed for me was an extra `</div>` lying around. Double check your html!

Comment: @maayanNaveh was the extra div in the page with the link or the page that was link to?

Comment: @DashiellRoseBark-Huss in the page with the link :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you could need to include the method in the form:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
```

to

```
<%= form_for(@user, method: :put) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried inserting the `:put` method as a parameter, but no luck. Could it perhaps be an issue with turbolinks failing to trigger the JS that causes the submit button to hit the update action?

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer to this part of the question: **Any help/ideas on ... how to better debug?**

A useful debugging tool for form issues is to open the page in the browser. Select to view page source and search on the string "form" to see exactly what html has been generated by the code.

For example, this is the html from one of my forms:

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="row">
    <form id="search-form" class="form-group" action="/locations" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="xxx" />
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm gx_ml_10 gx_mr_10">
      <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search for BBQ" class="form-control" />
     <span class="input-group-btn input-group-sm">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </button></span>
   </div> <!-- "input-group" --> 
  </form>     
 </div>  <!-- row -->
</div> <!-- "form-inline" -->
```

**Specifically in the html for the form section you are looking for:**

```
<button type="submit" ...
```

Without that, you have no form action.

---

**Addition/Revision**

**Another form debug suggestion** is to use an alert to see the hash at run time. To isolate differences between what is being passed to the controller with a direct URL access versus a "link_to" access, examine the hash created in both cases. Add this statement to user controller edit block.

```
flash[:info] = "Hash: #{params} User: #{@user.some_var_like_name}"
```

Comment: As an aside I never use "f.submit" -- it doesn't seem to work for me, although it is valid syntax. I use   <%= f.button :submit, label: "Submit", class: "xyz" %>

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried changing my submit erb to `<%= f.button :submit, :label => "Save changes", :class => "button expand radius small-3 columns" %>` but still no luck. The rendered HTML for the submit button is as follows... `<button name="button" type="submit" label="Save changes" class="button expand radius small-3 columns">submit</button>`. What's weird to me is that navigating to the form by typing the URL into the browser allows the form to work just fine. It's only when using links to arrive to the form that is having issues. Strange.

Comment: I added a hash debug technique and a few comments to the answer.