# Rails root form will only submit when entered directly in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, rails-routing

My root view has has a form, which renders but doesn't submit when a user reaches the page from a link:

```
<%= link_to 'home', root_path, class: 'navbar-brand' %>
```

If you access the root page directly through the browser (e.g. http://localhost:3000/, or refresh after link), the form submits.

Just getting started with rails (4.2), so I'm sure there's something really basic I'm missing. I'd really  appreciate advice!

Comment: What do you mean by `it doesn't submit`? Any server errors or errors in the console?

Comment: You may need to provide more information and code samples, eg what are you seeing in terms of error codes, in the console, is Turbolinks involved or some type of XHR request/javascript, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `data-no-turbolink="true"` inside your view's body tag.

Was solved by looking at [Form Submit button only works after reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365809/form-submit-button-only-works-after-reload).

Comment: If this is your final answer, please accept it to make the question as complete