# Form post does not work, when I go the form page through a link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a database for storing "share" values, which has many reviews. Inside share's show page, I am displaying 3 top reviews and also have a form to enter a new review. The problem is, when I press a refresh button(F5) when I am in the show page, and fill and submit the review form, it works fine. But, if I reach the show page from any other page using link_to option, the review form does not work. In such cases, when I click on the submit button, rails server does not generate any log.

The same thing happens in the "Review"'s index page as well. Along with all the reviews, I have a form(same code which is used in share show page, rendered through partial) to enter a new review. If I do a refresh in Review-> index page, and then fill the form and submit, the review gets saved in the database. But if I reach the "Review"'s index page through a link_to from "Share"'s show page, the review does not get saved in the database. I am not sure what is missing in my code.

Here is my code:

show controller:

```
def show
   @share = Share.find(params[:id])
   @reviews = @share.reviews.order(priority: :asc).limit(3)
   @newReview = @share.reviews.new
end
```

Form code inside show.html.erb : (I have removed html formatting here)

```
 <%= form_for([@share,@newReview])   do |f| %>
       <%= f.label :name %>
       <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true %>

       <%= f.label :priority %>
       <%= f.select :priority, Review::PRIORITY, prompt: "Pick one" %>

       <%= f.label :comment %>
       <%= f.text_area :comment, cols: 80 %>

       <%= f.submit 'Post Review'%>
  <% end %>
```

This code works, if I do a refresh button. but if I reach this show page, via a link, which is written as below, doesn't work:

```
 <%= link_to(@share.name, @share) %>
```

I am not able to understand why. Is it because a newReview instance is not included in the link? Can anybody help me please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got the answer from [Form Submit button only works after reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365809/form-submit-button-only-works-after-reload?rq=1). 
I can't have a form inside a table. After I moved it out of table, it is working fine.