# Rails submit button works only after reloading view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, rest, crud

I have a rails form that works well when creating a new model but is buggy when it comes to editing an existing one.

This is the behavior:

- When on the `edit` view, the submit button will not work.
- If I hit reload, once the `edit` view has rendered again, the button works fine, and I am able to submit any changes to the database.

Below is the code.

Form:

```
<%= form_for @client do |f| %>
    # Don't Think the problem is inside the form since it works after the reload.
    ...
    # Here is the button
    <button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right cms-button">
        <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i> Update Client
    </button>   
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def edit
  @client = Client.find( params[:id] )
end

def update
  @client = Client.find( params[:id] )
  if @client.update( client_params )
    flash[:notice] = "Client added succesfully"
    redirect_to( :action => 'show' )
  else
    render( 'edit)' )
  end
end
```

Where do I have to make changes so that the update is successful?

Comment: does this question help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365809/form-submit-button-only-works-after-reload?rq=1

Comment: Not exactly, but it helped motivated me to revert some HTML changes and test. The issue got fixed by doing this. If you post the answer I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: What changes did you revert in html? Would be useful for future users

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be an issue with the HTML that is unrelated to rails itself, this question has the same problem: [Form Submit button only works after reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365809/form-submit-button-only-works-after-reload?rq=1)