# Need to refresh a page with form to create on rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi guys i'm quite new in rails and I'm currently trying to understand how asynchronous calls are made :

I have this form that create a group, but when I press submit, nothing happens, I have to reload the page and do the same operation to make it happen.

```
<%= form_with model: @groupe, :url => new_groupe_path, :action => "create", :method => :POST, remote: true do |f| %>
<%= f.select :region, [['Île-de-France', 'Île-de-France' ], ['Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes', 'Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes'],
                          ['Bourgogne-Franche-Comté', 'Bourgogne-Franche-Comté'], ['Bretagne', 'Bretagne'], ['Centre-Val de Loire', 'Centre-Val de Loire'], ['Corse', 'Corse'], ['Grand Est', 'Grand Est'], ['Hauts-de-France', 'Hauts-de-France'], ['Normandie', 'Normandie'], ['Nouvelle-Aquitaine', 'Nouvelle-Aquitaine'], ['Occitanie', 'Occitanie'],
                          ['Pays de la Loire', 'Pays de la Loire'], ['Provences-Alpes-Côte d\'Azur', 'Provences-Alpes-Côte d\'Azur']] %>
```

I made some research on asynchronous call but didn't manage to solve it, any clue on how I can do this without refreshing the page ?

Comment: Are you intending for the request to be submitted via ajax? If not, try removing `, remove: true` from your form and it should work

Comment: Hi Mark, I removed the remote: true and it still needs the refresh

Answer (score 0):

[Form Submit button only works after reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365809/form-submit-button-only-works-after-reload)

From the post:

> I believe this is an HTML issue, not a Rails issue. Per this discussion Form inside a table,  can not be placed inside  or  or . After moving the  to wrap the table and putting the controls inside the respective  the form works.
>
> I still don't understand why refreshing the page made the form work, but...

If your form is within a table tag, restructure your HTML and it should work