# Form <select> value not submiting after the <select> are loaded by ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a form here
http://excavator.net.au/test1.php
 after blur the the postcode the suburb is loading with  dropdown with some option

here is the jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#zip").on('blur',function(){
        $.post("get_suburb_admin1.php",{zip:$(this).val()}, function(d){
            $("#suburb_cnt").html(d);
        });
    });

});
```

But when submit the form before ajax loading it getting fine.
But when it submit after ajax load it is not getting the value of suburb.
Please check the above url, solution is helpful for me.

Comment: Why would it send the value of `suburb`, the only value you're sending in the $.post function is the value of `#zip` ?

Comment: open the `form` before `table` and close it after `table`.

Comment: Have you tried returning, for example, a JSON and then adding manually the children of `#suburb_cnt`? Maybe just doing `$(el).html()` isn't enough for the browser to detect the `select` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the form before the table and close it after the table.

[First look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967564/form-inside-a-table)
and
[Second look](http://jsfiddle.net/gG8X8/1/)

```
<form action=""...>
    <table>
        <tr>
            ...
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

What does your console say, regarding `this`?  I believe the issue may be that `$(this)` inside of `$.post` refers to the `window` object, and **not** to `#zip`.  A couple other notes, too:

1. What it looks like you're attempting to do is send whatever value `#zip` has, which is an `input` element referring to the postcode (*not* to the suburb).
2. Since the `select` is going to be loaded dynamically, old handlers no longer apply.  However, you can delegate, like so:

   ```
   $(document).on('blur','#suburb',function() {
       //do whatever
   });
   ```
3. As far as context issues go for `this`, I believe `$.post` callbacks are called in the context of the `window`.  Try this to fix that issue, perhaps:

   ```
   $("#zip").on('blur',function(){
       var self = this;
       $.post("get_suburb_admin1.php",{zip:$(self).val()}, function(d){
           $("#suburb_cnt").html(d);
       });
   });
   ```

Overall it appears there could be several potential issues with your code, and with what you are trying to do.  I recommend you search for more information regarding AJAX, JavaScript function context, and jQuery selectors.

*Side note: you may want to reconsider how you are loading the `select` with your php, unless you are committed to it for a good reason.  Testing the webpage myself, it took almost 10 seconds at times for the `select` to load from your AJAX call.*

Comment: Sorry I have tried this code but same issue.. not getting the value after submit.Please see the url kindl. you can check the console also here..   http://excavator.net.au/test1.php

Answer (score 0):

Now I saw in firebug(tab NET) what data sending by submit.

**First**  `input[name=suburb1]` - its OK. POST all need fields.

**Second**  `onBlur` you replace  `input[name=suburb1]`   by   `select[name=suburb1]` (by `Ajax`). You can see that this 
select exists in DOM ( see in console). But it doesnt sending by POST (others fields - OK).
I dont know why its is  happening ( google silent).

I found one solution:

```
$("#frm input[type=submit]").submit(function(){
   // get value from "dynamic-ajax" select 
   var suburb = $("select[name=suburb1]").val();

   // adding hidden with same name & value 
   $('<input>').attr({
      type: 'hidden',
      name: 'suburb1',
      value: suburb,
   }).appendTo("#frm");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what your HTML look lke after your AJAX call.

The FORM has been rewrited and close just after the opening. So when you submit there is not input to pass.

```
<body>
<form name="frm" id="frm" action="test1.php" method="post" 
      enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>
<tbody><tr>
            <td>Address :</td>
            <td><input name="address" value="" type="text"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Suburb :</td>
            <td id="suburb_cnt"><select id="suburb" name="suburb1">
    <option value="ALEXANDRIA">ALEXANDRIA, New South Wales</option>
    <option value="BEACONSFIELD">BEACONSFIELD, New South Wales</option>
    <option value="EVELEIGH">EVELEIGH, New South Wales</option>
    </select></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Postcode :</td>
            <td><input name="zip" id="zip" value="" type="text"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>State :</td>
            <td id="state_cnt"><input name="state" id="state" value="" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input value="submit" name="submit" type="submit"></td>
        </tr>
```