# ParametersInterceptor error: Unexpected Exception caught, Error setting expression

Tags: java, html, jsp, parameters, struts2

I have a table inside a form that contains dropdowns and a hidden `input`.

**`JSP`:**

```jsp
<form action="modifyfaculty" method="post">
    <table>
        <thead class="center">
            <tr>
                <!-- column names here -->
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <c:forEach var="professor" items="${facultyList}">
                <tr>
                    <!-- more <td> -->

                    <td align="center">
                        <c:choose>
                            <c:when test="${professor.profEmplStatus.equals('FULL')}">
                                <select name="profEmplStatus" required>
                                    <option value="FULL" selected>FULL</option>
                                    <option value="PART">PART</option>
                                    <option value="RET">RET</option>
                                    <option value="TRMTD">TRMTD</option>
                                </select>
                            </c:when>

                            <!-- more <c:when> blocks -->
                        </c:choose>
                    </td>

                    <td align="center">
                        <c:choose>
                            <c:when test="${professor.profDept.equals('BSCS-SE')}">
                                <select name="profDept" required>
                                    <option value="BA-MMA">BA-MMA</option>
                                    <option value="BFDT">BFDT</option>
                                    <option value="BS-AN">BS-AN</option>
                                    <option value="BS-GPD">BS-GPD</option>
                                    <option value="BSBA-FM">BSBA-FM</option>
                                    <option value="BSBA-MKT">BSBA-MKT</option>
                                    <option value="BSCS-SE" selected>BSCS-SE</option>
                                    <option value="BSIT-WD">BSIT-WD</option>
                                    <option value="GENED">GENED</option>
                                </select>
                            </c:when>

                            <!-- more <c:when> blocks -->
                        </c:choose>
                    </td>

                    <td class="center">
                        <input type="hidden" name="profId" value="${professor.profId}" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

**`ModifyFacultyAction`:**

```java
public class ModifyFacultyAction extends ActionSupport {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer profId;
    private String profEmplStatus;
    private String profDept;

    @Override
    public String execute() {
        FacultyManager fm = new FacultyManager();
        fm.modifyFaculty("professor_employment_status", profEmplStatus, profId);
        fm.modifyFaculty("professor_department", profDept, profId);

        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public Integer getProfId() {
        return profId;
    }

    public void setProfId(Integer profId) {
        this.profId = profId;
    }

    public String getProfEmplStatus() {
        return profEmplStatus;
    }

    public void setProfEmplStatus(String profEmplStatus) {
        this.profEmplStatus = profEmplStatus;
    }

    public String getProfDept() {
        return profDept;
    }

    public void setProfDept(String profDept) {
        this.profDept = profDept;
    }
}
```

**`struts.xml`:**

```xml
<action name="modifyfaculty" class="com.mypackage.action.ModifyFacultyAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="notauth" />
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />

    <result type="redirectAction">
        <param name="actionName">viewfaculty</param>
    </result>

    <result name="input" type="redirectAction">
        <param name="actionName">viewfaculty</param>
    </result>

    <result name="index" type="redirect">/index.jsp</result>
</action>
```

**Output:**
[image]

However, upon choosing a new value from the dropdown and clicking `Save`, I am receiving an error. Below is the `devMode` log:

```
Jan 05, 2015 11:34:43 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor error
SEVERE: Developer Notification (set struts.devMode to false to disable this message):
Unexpected Exception caught setting 'profId' on 'class com.mypackage.action.ModifyFacultyAction: Error setting expression 'profId' with value ['100005', '100006', '100007', '100008', '100009', '100010', '100011', ]
Jan 05, 2015 11:34:43 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.LocalizedTextUtil warn
WARNING: Missing key [invalid.fieldvalue.profId] in bundles [[org/apache/struts2/struts-messages, com/opensymphony/xwork2/xwork-messages]]!
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Add `input` result and some tags (`actionerror`/`fielderror`) to jsp to see error(s).

Comment: I added the `<result name="input">`, but it must redirect to another action (`type="redirectAction"`) to render the needed JSP, so I cannot see the field error messages.

Comment: So don't redirect. Turn the dev mode on.

Comment: At the very least, I have narrowed down the cause to the form being submitted 7 times (the number of professors/database entries) when clicking `Save`, since the entire table is inside the form. I am still unsure of how to achieve the intended goal.

Comment: Do you want to save whole table at once? If not then create separate forms or whatever.

Comment: "create separate forms or whatever" - How to do that is what I'm hoping for as an answer, since it is illegal to put a `<tr>` in a `<form>`.

Comment: So basically your question is: how to put form inside table? Read the accepted answer of this question you've linked.

Comment: The accepted answer does not have the example. A comment was asking for an example (upvoted 5 times, including mine). I have also commented to notify the poster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to submit *all* ids of the table.  Because you don't want to convert `profId` to a list or array. Use a separate form for each record.

```jsp
<table>
    <thead class="center">
        <tr>
            <!-- column names here -->
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <c:forEach var="professor" items="${facultyList}">
          <tr><td>
          <form action="modifyfaculty" method="post">
          <table>
            <tr>
                <!-- more <td> -->

                <td align="center">
                    <c:choose>
                        <c:when test="${professor.profEmplStatus.equals('FULL')}">
                            <select name="profEmplStatus" required>
                                <option value="FULL" selected>FULL</option>
                                <option value="PART">PART</option>
                                <option value="RET">RET</option>
                                <option value="TRMTD">TRMTD</option>
                            </select>
                        </c:when>

                        <!-- more <c:when> blocks -->
                    </c:choose>
                </td>

                <td align="center">
                    <c:choose>
                        <c:when test="${professor.profDept.equals('BSCS-SE')}">
                            <select name="profDept" required>
                                <option value="BA-MMA">BA-MMA</option>
                                <option value="BFDT">BFDT</option>
                                <option value="BS-AN">BS-AN</option>
                                <option value="BS-GPD">BS-GPD</option>
                                <option value="BSBA-FM">BSBA-FM</option>
                                <option value="BSBA-MKT">BSBA-MKT</option>
                                <option value="BSCS-SE" selected>BSCS-SE</option>
                                <option value="BSIT-WD">BSIT-WD</option>
                                <option value="GENED">GENED</option>
                            </select>
                        </c:when>

                        <!-- more <c:when> blocks -->
                    </c:choose>
                </td>

                <td class="center">
                    <input type="hidden" name="profId" value="${professor.profId}" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
                </td>
            </tr>
           </table>
          </form>
         </td></tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi, from [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967564/form-inside-a-table), it says you cannot have a `<form>` inside `<tbody>`?

Comment: If you can include an example to Quentin's solution, I would be glad to accept the answer here and link that thread to this post (since it seems to be a popular question). =)

Comment: Use form inside a cell, then you need an internal table for the columns of the outer table. See updated code.

Comment: Hey, the nested tables worked, thanks! I upvoted it for working as it should. The tables just appeared messed up though ([screenshot](http://s11.postimg.org/p01u14fbn/tables.png)). Here is the updated code ([pastebin](http://pastebin.com/iZR5P98D)). How do I make it so it appears like the Output image in my original post?

Comment: It's different question, more likely to page design, please ask in another post. You can make link to this question of course. And you should know that if this answer worked for you should mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: All right, thanks. Figured it might be more appropriate as an HTML question. Marking as accepted as well. Will post another thread for the table formatting. I will also link this to Quentin's answer.

Comment: This is going to end up with tables that don't describe the actual data structure and which don't line up with each other. Better to use that approach I described in the linked to question.

Comment: Hi @Quentin, yes it had misaligned cells as you can see in my screenshot a few comments above (though I'm keeping this as the accepted answer, since it answered the original question regarding functionality). If you could put an example code snippet in your original answer in the other thread, that would be much helpful.

Comment: I don't see how an example would help at all. The two sentences explain it much more clearly than a couple of dozen lines of HTML and whatever server side language I feel like writing for the example would.

Comment: @Quentin, it would really help as there are requests for it. No need to show the server side, really. Just the HTML.

Comment: The HTML would be a couple of submit buttons. There's nothing complicated enough about it to benefit from an example.