# angular form with typeahead works on plunker/standalone but not in production code

Tags: angularjs, angular-foundation

I'm using a form within a table so I can submit some data in row. When I'm in my production/dev environment the form looks as follows. (I use route provider to assign the controller) Everything initially works as expected except that I cannot submit the form when pressing enter.

**HTML**

```
 <table>
     <tr>
         <form novalidate ng-submit="addResult(selectedFencer)">
         <td>
            <input type="search" ng-model="selectedFencer" typeahead="fencer for fencer in fencers"  placeholder="Type the fencers name" />
         </td>
         <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"  class="button" />
         </td>
         </form>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module('RankingsApp')
    .controller('CompetitionController', function($scope) {

        $scope.fencers = ["Scott","Laura", "James"];

        $scope.addResult = function(fencer) {
            alert(fencer)
        };
  });
```

However, if I put the same code into a plunker/standalone html file it works as expected with the form being submitted when enter is pressed.

http://plnkr.co/edit/3385qhpExge4S5ZdPs1E?p=preview

I initially assumed that my issue was to do with a code error, but if I move the form outside the table in my production code it works as expected.

```
<form novalidate ng-submit="addResult(selectedFencer)">
<table>
         <tr>

             <td>
                <input type="search" ng-model="selectedFencer" typeahead="fencer for fencer in fencers"  placeholder="Type the fencers name" />
             </td>
             <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit"  class="button" />
             </td>

         </tr>
     </table>
 </form>
```

Has anyone any suggestion on either how I could fix this or a direction I could take to debug it?

Comment: A `form` is not allowed inside a `table`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5967613/968155

Comment: @NewDev That wouldn't explain why it works in my Plunker or if I copy the plunker code to a local html file. Do you have any thoughts on why that would be?

Comment: Would you be minifying your files for production?

Comment: @Scott, I don't... but going against the spec is sure to lead to some unexpected behavior.

Comment: @itcouldevenbeaboat, no, I had thought that might be the issue but when I tested on Dev it again didn't work as expected.

Comment: I guess share a link of your code in production?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was able to find a solution by using HTML5 form attribute which I'll add below once the timer is up