# Coldfusion cfinput datefield not working inside table

Tags: html, html-table, coldfusion, datefield, cfinput

I've been stuck on this for a while, so any help would be appreciated. I am new to ColdFusion so all suggestions are welcome.

I am collecting data in a `cfform` that is then inserted into a SQL table, which works fine. Currently, the `cfform` is automatically generated using a cfloop inside an HTML table. For some reason though, the cfinput-datefield calendar is generating a JavaScript issue  unless the cfform is located in the same td, which isn't a viable option.

I've managed to make it work on a different page, and copy&pasted the code into this one but still to no avail. The JS error is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property split of undefined` however, this disappears as soon as, again, the cfform and cfinput are next to each other. Looking at the rendered code, it seems the cfform is closing itself off immediately, `<form...></form>` but unsure of what to make of this.

Both get_vessel_info and get_container_info are cfqueries from before that work perfectly. All the variables have correctly been defined too.

Here is my code:

```
<cfoutput>
<table name="main-table">
    <tr class="titlerow">
        <td>#invoiceno#*</td>
        <td>#dateofentry#*</td>
        <td>#containerno#</td>
        <td>#sealno#</td>
        <td>#insurancecoefficient#*</td>
        <td>#freightperkilo#*</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <cfif get_vessel_info.number_of_containers gte 1>
        <cfloop from="1" to="#get_vessel_info.number_of_containers#" index="i">
            <cfform action="inboundcontainerinsert.cfm?vessel_ID=#session.vessel_ID#" name="containerinsertrow#i#" method="post">
            <tr>
                <td><cfinput type="text" name="invoice_no#i#" placeholder="#entervalue#" maxlength="50" required="yes" value="#invoicenovalue#"></td>
                <td><cfinput type="datefield" name="date_of_entry#i#" placeholder="#selectvalue#" maxlength="50" required ="yes" value="#dateofentryvalue#" mask="DD-MMM-YYYY"></td>
                <td><cfinput type="text" name="container_no#i#" placeholder="#entervalue#" maxlength="50"  value="#containernovalue#"></td>
                <td><cfinput  type="text" name="seal_no#i#" placeholder="#entervalue#" maxlength="50"  value="#sealnovalue#"></td>
                <td><cfinput type="text" name="insurance_coefficient#i#" maxlength="50" required="yes" value="#insurance_covalue#"></td>
                <td><cfinput type="text" name="freightperkg#i#" placeholder="#entervalue#" maxlength="50" required="yes" value="#freightperkgvalue#"></td>
                <cfif #container_id# NEQ "">
                    <cfset submitname = 'updaterow'><cfset submitvalue = #freightstore_updaterow#> 
                <cfelse>
                    <cfset submitname = 'submitrow'><cfset submitvalue = #freightstore_submitrow#>
                </cfif>
                <td><cfinput type="submit" name="#submitname#" value="#submitvalue#"/></td>
        </tr></cfform>
    </cfloop>
```

Am open to any suggestion. I do not know jQuery or Ajax so am hesitant to use them unless someone amazing can create a perfectly working fix. I have included a `<cfajaximport tags="cfinput-datefield">` but to no avail.

If you have any questions, please feel free to ask.

Comment: Because `cfinput`. Do not use `cfform`, `cfinput`, or any other client side functionality of ColdFusion. They outdated, poorly implemented and woefully limited. Try searching for date pickers on Google, there are plenty out there that work better and are easier to work with. Also, don't use tables to layout your form. That is so 1990's

Comment: Thanks @Scott Stroz. I normally wouldn't use a table but time is limited and would rather improve functionality than presentation. A table works perfect to display the information. If I just use a `form`, I get issues passing data backwards and forwards, was hoping to not have to recode the whole page...is this the only thing possible?

Comment: *seems the cfform is closing itself off immediately* Ignoring the inherent challenges of using the CF form control stuff to begin with, it does not look like your html is valid. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967564/form-inside-a-table..

Comment: @Leigh thanks! I'll try it when I get back to my computer and let you know how that goes

Comment: @Leigh, you're a star. Thank you so much! Such a stupid mistake haha I know for next time at least

Comment: While I am quite willing to use cfform and it's associated elements, I refuse to use the datefield.  Given that it's a flash movie, it takes too long to load.  Plus it's not accessible by keystrokes.  There are lot's of javascript alternatives out there.  Your users will thank you for finding one.

Comment: Duly noted. If time allows, I will go back and find an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

After painstakingly debugging this I have found the table needs to START inside the  tag and not reversed. Hope this saves some people some time!