# How to resolve the following HTML error?

Tags: html, django-templates

I have the following lines in my django template file:-cart.html:-

```
<td class="right">
    <form method="post" action="." class="cart">
        <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
        <input type="text" name="quantity" value="{{ item.quantity }}" id="quantity" size="2" class="quantity" maxlength="5" />
        <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="{{ item.id }}" />
</td>
<td>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" />
    </form>
</td>
```

At the first closing tag of td i.e is the first    `</td>`,i get the following error:
Element form is not closed.Please help me to rectify this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML tags** must be structured in a directly **hierarchic manner**. Closing a tag that was opened inside previously closed elements is incorrect and will often produce errors and issues.

Enclose the form inside the table data, like this:

```
<td class="right">
    <form method="post" action="." class="cart">
        <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
        <input type="text" name="quantity" value="{{ item.quantity }}" id="quantity" size="2" class="quantity" maxlength="5" />
        <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="{{ item.id }}" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" />
    </form>
</td>
```

or enclose either the whole table or the table elements inside the form, like this:

```
<form method="post" action="." class="cart">
    <td class="right">
        <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
        <input type="text" name="quantity" value="{{ item.quantity }}" id="quantity" size="2" class="quantity" maxlength="5" />
        <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="{{ item.id }}" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" />
    </td>
</form>
```

I assume the latter solution is the one you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Well, try tabbing the first line so that it is lined up with its closing tag.

Then I'd fiddle with the code for bit and try out things. Here's a good article to look at: http://help.simplytestable.com/errors/html-validation/end-tag-for-element-x-which-is-not-open/end-tag-for-element-form-which-is-not-open/

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to put the form across multiple `td`s, that will be difficult with your current approach.

Unfortunately, you can't have the form inside a table row, and your current HTML is invalid since the `td` element is closed before the `form` element.

You either need to:

1. have the whole table in the form
2. Have the whole form in a table cell.
3. Use the html5 form attribute

See [Form inside a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967564/form-inside-a-table)