# form rendering as blank in html laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a form that rendering as blank in HTML (for no reason that I can see), but the values are still being sent through to Laravel. This wouldn't bother me except I need to be able to change the button text and have a way to copy the from, neither of which will work because the form is technically empty. Below is a screenshot of what the form is outputting.

[image]

The code looks like this:

```
@foreach( $Contractors as $contractor )

{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'ContractorInvoicing.store', 'class' => 'form-inline InvoiceForm')); !!}

<tr {!! checkRDO($contractor->RDOCat, $TheDate) !!}>
    <td>{!! $contractor->Surname; !!}, {!! $contractor->name; !!} </td>
<td>{!! $contractor->PRN; !!} {!! Form::hidden('PRN', $contractor->PRN); !!} {!! Form::hidden('thedate', $TheDate); !!} {!! Form::hidden('id', ''); !!}</td>
<td>{!! Form::text('StartTime', '', array('class' => 'form-control StartTime required', 'id' => 'TimePicker', 'tabindex' => '1')); !!}</td>
<td>{!! Form::text('FinishTime', '', array('class' => 'form-control FinishTime required', 'tabindex' => '2')); !!}</td>
<td>{!! Form::text('BreakTime', '', array('class' => 'form-control BreakTime required', 'tabindex' => '3')); !!}</td>
<td>{!! Form::text('grade', '', array('class' => 'form-control required', 'tabindex' => '4')); !!}</td>
<td>{!! Form::checkbox('PM', '1', false, array('class' => 'form-control')); !!}</td>
<td>{!! Form::checkbox('NS', '1', false, array('class' => 'form-control')); !!}</td>
<td>{!! Form::checkbox('RDO', '1', false, array('class' => 'form-control')); !!}</td>
<td>{!! Form::text('OrdHours', $OrdHours, array('class' => 'form-control')); !!}</td>
<td>{!! Form::text('OT150', '3.0', array('class' => 'form-control')); !!}</td>
<td>{!! Form::select('AreaPosition', $DepartmentCodes, $contractor->AreaPosition, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}</td>
<td>{!! Form::select('Company', $Company, $contractor->Company, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}</td>
<td>{!! Form::submit('Submit', array('class' => 'btn btn-default submitInvoice', 'tabindex' => '5')); !!}</td>
<td><a href="#" class="AddRow">Add</a></td>
</tr>
{!! Form::close(); !!}

 @endforeach
```

Comment: I'd bet there's a `display: none` somewhere.

Comment: It's not set to display: none, I'm just using Bootstrap. I have other forms on the site with the same class and they're rendering correctly.

Comment: Well, whatever's happening, it's not in that code in your post.

Answer (score 0):

[Form tag cannot be an immediate child of a tbody tag.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967564/form-inside-a-table)

Try wrapping the `<form>` tag around the `<table>` tag

Comment: It's not like that please visit reference link that you have given, he can not do like <table><form><td></td></form> but he can do like <table><tr><td><form></form></td></tr></table> so @QuickBen is correct

Comment: In the screenshot you provided form is a child element of tbody. The answer in the link provided states that it is not allowed. Have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: You can have an entire table inside a form. You can have a form inside a table cell. You cannot have part of a table inside a form.

Use one form around the entire table. Then either use the clicked submit button to determine which row to process (to be quick) or process every row (allowing bulk updates).

Comment: Looking at your screenshot you have <tbody><form><tr> which is wrong

Comment: But table cell can contain form. :-)

Comment: Yes, table cells can contain forms. Your form isn't inside a table cell thus the issue

Comment: Thanks for changing your answer.

Comment: Seems you were picking holes in it instead of accepting so I improved it. You're welcome!