# ng-disabled behaving strangely

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm running into an odd issue while trying to set `ng-disabled` on my 'Save' button in the code below. I want my input field to be required and to be a non-negative number. This code works great as structured, but when I remove that second form below my table `ng-disabled` no longer works. Why does ng-disabled depend on this completely unnecessary additional form which I purely added for temporary testing purposes?

```
<div>  
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><p>Limit</p></td>
      <td><p>1,000,000</p></td>
      <form class="form-inline" name="form">
        <td>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" ng-pattern="/^[0-9][0-9]*$/" class="form-control" ng-if="limit.saveAllowed" ng-model="limit.user.points"
               ng-required="true"></input>
          </div>
          <p ng-if="!limit.saveAllowed">{{limit.user.points}}</p>
        </td>
        <td ng-if="limit.saveAllowed">
          <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" ng-click='limit.setLimit(limit.user.points)' ng-disabled="form.$invalid">Save</button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </form>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <form class="form-inline" name="form">
    <input type="text" ng-model="limit.user.points"
       ng-required="true"></input>
  </form>
</div>
```

Note: I am using the `controllerAs` syntax so `limit` refers to my controller. Further, this HTML all resides within a custom directive's template. I don't know if that additional info is helpful, but I'm stumped.

Comment: could you create plunkr of this problem?

Comment: not sure if it's the issue but your form isn't nested in a `<td>` but directly in a `<tr>` which is not allowed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967564/form-inside-a-table

Comment: @NexusDuck, thank you! That was exactly the problem. I simply moved the form element outside my table and that solved it. Please post your comment as an answer so I can credit you.

Comment: @MattDionis You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms can not be nested directly inside a `<tr>`(see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967564/form-inside-a-table)). 
Simply wrap the form with a `<td>` (or just move it outside the `<table>`) and things should work.