# Dynamically added row is not visualised HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to dynamically add a row, with a form, inside a table, upon the click of a button. Here's the JS code chunk:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.can_add_bank_row = true;
    $('#add_bank_acc_btn').on('click', function () {
        addBankAccRow();
    });
});
/**
 *  Adds a table row with fields to add a bank account to the user's profile.
 */
function addBankAccRow() {
    if (window.can_add_bank_row) {
        var warning_msg = "You are about to add a new bank account for this user.\n\nAre you sure?";
        $('<tr>' +
            '<form id="addNewBankAccountForm" method="POST" onsubmit=\"return confirm(\'' + warning_msg + '\');\">' +
            '</tr>').insertBefore('#bank_accs_tbl > tbody > tr:first');
        $('#addNewBankAccountForm').html(
            '<td></td>' +
            '<td><select id="bank_type_dropdown">' +
            '<option value="international">International</option>' +
            '<option value="sepa">SEPA</option>' +
            '<option value="interac">Interac</option>' +
            '<option value="paypal">PayPal</option>' +
            '</select></td>' +
            '<td><input name="add_bank_label_input" type="text"></td>' +
            '<td><input name="add_bank_currency_input" type="text" style="width: 50px;"></td>' +
            '<td><input name="add_bank_min_transfer_input" type="text" style="width: 80px;"></td>' +
            '<td><input type="checkbox" name="add_bank_approved" value="0"></td>' +
            '<td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button></td>'
        );
        window.can_add_bank_row = false;
    } else {
        alert('You\'ve got one empty row to add a bank account already.\nPlease, fill and submit it before adding a new one. :)');
    }
}
```

When I check the source of the page, I can see the form and all its elements in the code, but it just doesn't appear visually.
// [jsfiddle for this ^](https://jsfiddle.net/zd8L57L1/)

If I try this instead:

```
$('<tr>' +
            '<form method="POST" onsubmit=\"return confirm(\'' + warning_msg + '\');\">' +
            '<td></td>' +
            '<td><select id="bank_type_dropdown">' +
            '<option value="international">International</option>' +
            '<option value="sepa">SEPA</option>' +
            '<option value="interac">Interac</option>' +
            '<option value="paypal">PayPal</option>' +
            '</select></td>' +
            '<td><input name="add_bank_label_input" type="text"></td>' +
            '<td><input name="add_bank_currency_input" type="text" style="width: 50px;"></td>' +
            '<td><input name="add_bank_min_transfer_input" type="text" style="width: 80px;"></td>' +
            '<td><input type="checkbox" name="add_bank_default" value="0"></td>' +
            '<td><input type="checkbox" name="add_bank_approved" value="0"></td>' +
            '<td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button></td>' +
            '</form>' +
            '</tr>').insertBefore('#bank_accs_tbl > tbody > tr:first');
```

then the form tag is auto-closed and the input fields and the submit button are left outside the form...

// [jsfiddle for this one ^](https://jsfiddle.net/t5x5p2xq/)

Aaaand, I also tried this one:

```
$('<form id="addNewBankAccountForm" method="POST" onsubmit=\"return confirm(\'' + warning_msg + '\');\">'
        ).insertBefore('#bank_accs_tbl > tbody > tr:first');
        $('#addNewBankAccountForm').html(
            '<tr>' +
            '<td></td>' +
            '<td><select id="bank_type_dropdown">' +
            '<option value="international">International</option>' +
            '<option value="sepa">SEPA</option>' +
            '<option value="interac">Interac</option>' +
            '<option value="paypal">PayPal</option>' +
            '</select></td>' +
            '<td><input name="add_bank_label_input" type="text"></td>' +
            '<td><input name="add_bank_currency_input" type="text" style="width: 50px;"></td>' +
            '<td><input name="add_bank_min_transfer_input" type="text" style="width: 80px;"></td>' +
            '<td><input type="checkbox" name="add_bank_approved" value="0"></td>' +
            '<td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button></td>' +
            '</tr>'
        );
```

Now the row, along with the inputs, are visualised, but all in the first cell... I can't handle front-end, I'm a backend guys. Please help :D

// [and its jsfiddle ^](https://jsfiddle.net/8rvahn1w/)

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, as only `th` and `td` elements can be direct child of `tr`. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/spec.html#tr Thus your browser is modifying the HTML which you are supplying

Comment: can you please provide the fiddle of your code ?

Comment: You can not put a <form> element inside a table.
Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967564/form-inside-a-table

Comment: I updated my post with one more solution and JSfiddle for all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright... apparently, as @Satpal said and @david posted a help link, `<form>` cannot be a direct child of `table`, `th` or `tr`. It will auto-close and stuff you don't want to happen will eventually happen.

The solution I though of is to (as in many other cases) have `hidden` input fields inside the form, which on its side will be enclosed in a single, separate self, together with the `submit` button. And these hidden fields will eventually acquire the data from the visible input fields, and then submitted.

Here's the code:

```
var warning_msg = "You are about to add a new bank account for this merchant.\n\nAre you sure?";
        $('<tr>' +
            '<td></td>' +
            '<td><select id="add_bank_type_dropdown_input">' +
            '<option value="international">International</option>' +
            '<option value="sepa">SEPA</option>' +
            '<option value="interac">Interac</option>' +
            '<option value="paypal">PayPal</option>' +
            '</select></td>' +
            '<td><input id="add_bank_label_input" name="add_bank_label_input" type="text"></td>' +
            '<td><input id="add_bank_currency_input" name="add_bank_currency_input" type="text" style="width: 50px;"></td>' +
            '<td><input id="add_bank_min_transfer_input" name="add_bank_min_transfer_input" type="text" style="width: 80px;"></td>' +
            '<td><input id="add_bank_approved_input" type="checkbox" name="add_bank_approved" value="0"></td>' +
            '<td>' +
            '<form method="POST" onsubmit=\"return confirm(\'' + warning_msg + '\');\">' +
            '<input id="add_bank_type_dropdown_hidden" type="hidden">' +
            '<input id="add_bank_label_hidden" type="hidden">' +
            '<input id="add_bank_currency_hidden" type="hidden">' +
            '<input id="add_bank_min_transfer_hidden" type="hidden">' +
            '<input id="add_bank_approved_hidden" type="hidden">' +
            '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>' +
            '</form>' +
            '</td>' +
            '</form>' +
            '</tr>').insertBefore('#bank_accs_tbl > tbody > tr:first');
```

and then I do:

```
$('#add_bank_type_dropdown_hidden').val($('#add_bank_type_dropdown_input').val());
            $('#add_bank_type_label_hidden').val($('#add_bank_type_label_input').val());
            $('#add_bank_type_currency_hidden').val($('#add_bank_type_currency_input').val());
            $('#add_bank_type_min_transfer_hidden').val($('#add_bank_type_min_transfer_input').val());
            if ($('#add_bank_type_approved_input').is('checked')) {
                $('#add_bank_type_approved_hidden').val(1);
            } else {
                $('#add_bank_type_approved_hidden').val(0);
            }
            $('#addNewBankAccountForm').submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Before clarifying why it isn't adding I would like to tell, as others
>   said your `html` will not be valid structure then, for the reasons or
>   proofs mentioned in comments. Also when you execute the below code of
>   inserting the whole stuff, your `table` gets messed up after
>   insertion.

**Clarification for your question**

> You have `insertBefore('#bank_accs_tbl > tbody > tr:first');` where in
>   you are trying to insert the element created before
>   **table-tbody-first tr** where in as I see your `html` there **isn't** any `tbody` itself and you just have `thead` and `table` closed. So
>   first you need to add `tbody` and an empty `tr` so as to pose
>   `tbody`'s first `tr` is present in `DOM`. Otherwise your `selector`
>   for `insertBefore` will not be found in `HTML DOM`. Below should be
>   your `table`  structure at beginning:

```
<table id="bank_accs_tbl" class="table table-striped">
     <thead>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Bank type</th>
        <th>Label</th>
        <th>Currency</th>
        <th>Min. transfer</th>
        <th>Approved</th>
        <th></th>
     </thead>
     <tbody><!--Add this part-->
        <tr>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/8rvahn1w/)**