# Display <select> in each table row by using the same database table data

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm going to construct a table to let my user enter their SPM result then my system will filter and show them which course is eligible to apply.

I've tried to make 10 rows in a table and each row consisted of 2 `<select>`, one is SPM subject and another one is the grade they obtained. The options of Subject and Grade were fetch from my database.

[image: Database table - spm_subject]
[image: Database table - spm_grade]

Here is my coding for my table:

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM spm_subject");
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM spm_grade");
?>

<table class="p1" bgcolor="#FFFFCC" bordercolor="#000000" align="center" width="771" border="2">
    <tr>
        <td><div align="center"><strong>No.</strong></div></td>
        <td><div align="center"><strong>Subject Name</strong></div></td>
        <td><div align="center"><strong>Grade</strong></div></td>
    </tr>
<form action="checkresult2.php">
<?php 
    for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++)
    {?>
    <tr>
        <td width="44"><div align="center"><?php echo $i; ?></div></td>
        <td width="601">
            <select>
                <option value="">--- Please choose a subject ---</option>
                <?php
                    while($s = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                    {?>
                        <option name="subj"><?php echo $s["name"]; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td width="104"><div align="center">
            <select>
                <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
                <?php
                    while($g = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
                    {?>
                        <option name="grad"><?php echo $g["grade"]; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <div align="center">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</form>
</table>
```

The table was constructed but only the FIRST ROW able to display data from the both database tables inside the both `<select>`.

Any solution to solve this problem?

Comment: *Any solution to solve this problem?* What problem. ? You have not mention your problem.

Comment: each row must have a `select` with ALL `name` fields and another with ALL `grade` fields?

Comment: What error you are getting @Wong ?

Comment: @NanaPartykar First row of the table is able to display the table data inside <select> only, but others cannot

Comment: @fusion3k Exactly, all the table data can be displayed inside `<select>`

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/k5bybke6k7hpuwl/Capture3.PNG?dl=0
Kindly have a look at my output..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** Remove `<form>` inside `<table>`. Because, A form is not allowed to be a child element of a table, tbody or tr. You can have an entire table inside a form. You can have a form inside a table cell. You cannot have part of a table inside a form. For more info, click [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967564/form-inside-a-table)

**2)** `<option>` don't have `name` attribute. Check  [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_value.asp)

**3)** Give `name` to `<select></select>` . Check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_name.asp)

**4)** Since, multiple values are being submitted to **checkresult2.php** page, you have to define name as `name="subj[]"` and `name="grad[]"` as `array` type.

**5)** An Alternative way for showing data in rest 9 rows is : before `while loop` give that `query` there itself, like below.

**Updated Code.**

```
<form action="checkresult2.php">
    <table class="p1" bgcolor="#FFFFCC" bordercolor="#000000" align="center" width="771" border="2">
          <tr>
              <td><div align="center"><strong>No.</strong></div></td>
              <td><div align="center"><strong>Subject Name</strong></div></td>
              <td><div align="center"><strong>Grade</strong></div></td>
          </tr>

            <?php 
          for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++)
          {?>
          <tr>
              <td width="44"><div align="center"><?php echo $i; ?></div></td>
              <td width="601">
                  <select name="subj[]">
                      <option value="">--- Please choose a subject ---</option>
                          <?php
                          $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM spm_subject");
                          while($s = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                          {?>
                              <option value="<?php echo $s['name']; ?>"><?php echo $s["name"]; ?></option>
                      <?php } ?>
                  </select>
              </td>
              <td width="104"><div align="center">
                  <select name="grad[]">
                      <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
                          <?php
                          $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM spm_grade");
                          while($g = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
                          {?>
                              <option value="<?php echo $g['grade']; ?>"><?php echo $g["grade"]; ?></option>
                      <?php } ?>
                  </select>
              </div>
              </td>
          </tr>
            <?php }?>
          <tr>
              <td colspan="3">
                  <div align="center">
                      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                  </div>
              </td>
          </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

[**NOTE**: **mysql_** is deprecated in `PHP 5.5.0`, and it was removed in `PHP 7.0.0`. Use **MySQLi** or **PDO_MySQL** extension should be used.]

Comment: Hey @WongJuinHao : Glad to hear that. But, please keep in mind those 5 points. *Enjoy* *Cheers !*

Comment: I will do that! Thanks for your guidance!

Comment: Nice answer, well-explained; *love it*.

Comment: I'm learning form you @Fred-ii-. I also want to give answer as you give. In simple words, you are my *ideal* in stack overflow.

Comment: You're too kind Nana, *grazie mille!*

Answer (score 0):

You have to preprocess the query populating two arrays:

```
$names = $grades = array();
for( $i=1; $i<=10; $i++ ) 
{
    $names[] = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result );
    $grades[] = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result2 );
}
```

Then, in our code:

```
<?php foreach( $names as $key => $name ) {?>
    <option name="subj"><?php echo $name['name']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

and

```
<?php foreach( $grades as $key => $grade ) {?>
    <option name="grad"><?php echo $grade['grade']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

`mysql_fetch_assoc` fetch the current row from results and then ‘go’ to next row, so when the first `for` loop is terminate, the cursor has reached the end of results and - in next `for` loops, there is nothing to fetch.

#### Please note:

> `mysql_` syntax was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and **it was removed** in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

Comment: Although it's not worked but still have to thank you for the tips!

Comment: @WongJuinHao I have tested it and it works as expected.