# How can I subtract a user input value from a value in a MySQL table only if the value in the field is equal to or greater than the input value?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form which contains input fields `item id`, `staff id`, and `quantity`. I want to update a table whenever is press *issue*. I want the value I submit, that is the quantity to be subtracted only if it is less than or equal to the quantity value already in the destination table.
Below is my code.

**The form:**

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("dbtest", $con);

$result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM recieved_orders");
echo "<table border = '1' style='margin-left:18px;margin-right:18px;' bgcolor='#CFC'>
                <tr>
                    <th bgcolor='#34495E' colspan='9'>
                        <h1><font color='white' align='center'>&nbsp&nbsp&nbspORDER OFFICE SUPPLIES</font></h1>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr bgcolor='#CFC' font size='18'>
                    <th>Item Id</th>
                    <th>Staff Id</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                </tr>";

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<form action=\"Updateisue.php\" method=\"post\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">";
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"ItemId\"  size=\"30\" value=\" ". $row ['ItemId'] . "\" readonly></td>";
                    echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"StaffId\" value=\" ". $row ['StaffId'] . "\" readonly></td>";
                    echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"Quantity\" value=\" ".$row ['Quantity'] . "\" readonly></td>";
                    echo "<td><input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" size=\"30\" style='background-color:#3366FF' value=\"ISSUE  \"></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            echo "</form>";
        }
echo "</table>";
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

**Form action:**

```
<?php
include './database-config.php';
$searchError = "";
$searchMessage = "";

function sanitizeString($var) {
    $var = htmlentities($var);
    $var = strip_tags($var);
    $var = stripslashes($var);
    $var = trim($var);
    return $var;
}
$ItemId = sanitizeString($_POST['ItemId']);
$Quantity = sanitizeString($_POST['Quantity']);

if($Quantity<=Quantity){
    $updatePassQuery = "UPDATE stationery SET Quantity=Quantity-$Quantity WHERE ItemId='$ItemId'";
    $executeQuery = mysqli_query($dbh,$updatePassQuery);
if($executeQuery){
    echo " update successful";
    $message  = "update was successful";
    header("location: procurementhome.php");

    } else{
        echo "unsuccessful";
        $error = "update failed";
        // header("location: upstationery.php");
    }
}
else
{
    echo "no more itmes";
}
?>
```

Comment: What is this `$Quantity<=Quantity` ? From where `Quantity` comes here ?

Comment: Hi @musyimi : You didn't responded to answer. ?

Comment: Could you give some more details on your code, please? For example, what exactly is not working or where exactly are you missing the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** `<form>` is not allowed inside a `<table>`. Check [form-inside-a-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967564/form-inside-a-table)

**2)** You have to keep one submit button for all the details. Do whatever changes there and submit.

**3)** According to Point 2, `name` of input have to be array type. (Check answer below)

**4)** In **Updateisue.php**, using `for loop` or `foreach` find each `ItemId` and execute query.

**5)** In this line `if($Quantity<=Quantity){`. I don't know from where you get `Quantity` value. But, still. What i assumed is : `Quantity` for that particular `ItemId`. So, I wrote one query to execute to find quantity.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("dbtest", $con);
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM recieved_orders");

echo "<form action=\"Updateisue.php\" method=\"post\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">";
    echo "<table border = '1' style='margin-left:18px;margin-right:18px;' bgcolor='#CFC'>
                    <tr>
                        <th bgcolor='#34495E' colspan='9'>
                            <h1><font color='white' align='center'>&nbsp&nbsp&nbspORDER OFFICE SUPPLIES</font></h1>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr bgcolor='#CFC' font size='18'>
                        <th>Item Id</th>
                        <th>Staff Id</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                    </tr>";

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                    echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"ItemId[]\"  size=\"30\" value=\" ". $row ['ItemId'] . "\" readonly></td>";
                        echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"StaffId[]\" value=\" ". $row ['StaffId'] . "\" readonly></td>";
                        echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"Quantity[]\" value=\" ".$row ['Quantity'] . "\" readonly></td>";
                        echo "<td><input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" size=\"30\" style='background-color:#3366FF' value=\"ISSUE  \"></td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "<tr><td colspan='3'></td><td><input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" size=\"30\" style='background-color:#3366FF' value=\"ISSUE  \"></td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

**Updateisue.php**

```
<?php
include './database-config.php';
$searchError = "";
$searchMessage = "";

function sanitizeString($var) {
    $var = htmlentities($var);
    $var = strip_tags($var);
    $var = stripslashes($var);
    $var = trim($var);
    return $var;
}

$totalItem = sizeof($_POST['ItemId']);
$Quantity = $_POST['Quantity'];
for($i=0;$i<$totalItem;$i++) {

    $CItemId = sanitizeString($ItemId[$i]);
    $CQuantity = sanitizeString($Quantity[$i]);

    $quantityAvailable = mysqli_query("SELECT Quantity FROM stationery WHERE ItemId='$CItemId ");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($quantityAvailable,MYSQLI_ASSOC); 
    $quantityDB = $row['Quantity'];

    if($CQuantity<=$quantityDB){
        $updatePassQuery = "UPDATE stationery SET Quantity=Quantity-$CQuantity WHERE ItemId='$CItemId'";
        $executeQuery = mysqli_query($dbh,$updatePassQuery);
        if($executeQuery){
            echo " update successful";
            $message  = "update was successful";
            header("location: procurementhome.php");
        } else{
                echo "unsuccessful";
                $error = "update failed";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "no more itmes";
    }
}

?>
```