# Unable to get property 'FromDate' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript

I have an asp page with a Jscript calendar in it but keep getting the message below

****Unable to get property 'FromDate' of undefined or null reference****

The code I've run is:

```
<INPUT class=DateButton style="POSITION: relative" onclick="ShowCalendar(this.form.FromDate.value,  this,  this.form.FromDate)" type=button value=" >>> " name=cmdShowCalendar>
    </TD></TR>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that `this.form` is `undefined` or `null`. That means that the input doesn't belong to a form. So either:

- Put it in a `<form>`
- Use the `form` attribute to identify the form it belongs to
- Use some other DOM method to find the element you are trying to reference

Comment: @TimHarnett — Below what? Without seeing the code, and based on that statement, my best guess is [that you have this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967564/form-inside-a-table) and that you should use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org/nu/)

Comment: @TimHarnett — Edit the question. Put the HTML into the **question**. Not the ASP, the HTML that the ASP outputs. See [MCVE]

Comment: <HTML> <form NAME="FOREXEnquiry" ACTION="FOREXEnquiry2.asp" METHOD="post" onSubmit="submitonce(this)">
  <font face="Arial" size=2>
<CENTER></HTML>

Comment: @TimHarnett — Click edit and put the code in the question. Don't put it in a comment. Make sure it is a [MCVE]