# Insert form element between tr and td when creating HTML Table

Tags: html, css

I have tried to create a table using normal html.

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <td> Hello </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

But, currently, i have a task to insert a form element without affecting the table structure. so it looks like this

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <form><td>hello</td></form>
 </tr>
</table>
```

How should the form' css look like?

Comment: It is really hard styling tables. Especially when it comes to this. I'd rather insert a new row, having only one cell expanding over all columns

Comment: how to do it? any reference?

Comment: `<td colspan="the number of columns you have"><form class="whatever-you-want">your form</form></td>`

Comment: how to force the form to expand through all columns? it seems your method not working for me, because i switch the view part and the form part, it may affect the view part if the td colspan="6"

Comment: Please look at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967564/form-inside-a-table) :)