# <input> cannot appear as a child of <tr>

Tags: html, reactjs

I want to add a `<input>` element, more specifically a checkbox, in my table. The following works:

```
<tbody key={rule._id}>
  <tr>
    <td>{rule.deviceId}</td>
    {
      <input
        name="isEnabled"
        type="checkbox"
        checked={rule.enabled}
      />
    }
    <td>{rule.name}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

but it produces an error in the console: `<input> cannot appear as a child of <tr>`

Is there a 'proper' way to do this?

Comment: yea, put it inside <td>

Comment: I think you missed one `<td></td>` pair. You need to wrap your `input` into one

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967564/form-inside-a-table)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Put the `<input>` inside a `<td>`.

Comment: god dammit! Cheers

Answer (score 3):

You missed one `<td>` pair. Also the `{` and `}` are not required. Should be like that

```
<tbody key={rule._id}>
  <tr>
    <td>{rule.deviceId}</td>
    <td>
      <input
        name="isEnabled"
        type="checkbox"
        checked={rule.enabled} />
    </td>
    <td>{rule.name}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

`tr` can only contain `td`. You should wrap your `input` with a `td`.

```
<tbody key={rule._id}>
  <tr>
    <td>{rule.deviceId}</td>
    <td> 
      <input
        name="isEnabled"
        type="checkbox"
        checked={rule.enabled}
      />
    </td>
    <td>{rule.name}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must put it in a `<td>` Element, and you can add styles to the `<td>` DOM.