# My PHP submit button does not work. How to solve it?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, form-submit, submit-button

I am using Laravel 5 and I have some forms in one page. All is works except the last one. It is nothing happen, no error. I tried to put alert in the button. The alert showed, but the data won't saved.

```
<tr>
  <div>
    <form action="{{ url('AddComment') }}" method="POST">
      <div>
      <td>
        <textarea class="form-control edit" id="com_comment2" name="com_comment2" style="width:90%"  placeholder="Type a New Comment.." required=""></textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="com_leads2" value="{{ $leads[0]->LED_CODE }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
        <button id ="af" class="btn btn-round btn-success">Submit</button>
      </td>
    </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</tr>
```

Comment: Check the answer @hendraspt.

Comment: Hi @hendraspt please button type submit use in code like this 
 <button type="submit" id ="af" class="btn btn-round btn-success">

Comment: oopps sorry, I already put `type='submit'` before but still the same. I'm trying to put it again and still the same

Comment: `data won't saved` ? Does you save the data using `::create()` method? Do you put already the fields inside `$fillable` property?

Comment: You can't place the form as a child element of table ,tbody, tr .  Here is your solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967564/form-inside-a-table

Comment: when you disable javascript in your browser, does the form then submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the answer to helping me. I have tried it all but still nothing happen. But I looked at @JYoThI comment which said 'You can't place the form as a child element of table ,tbody, tr .' then I moved the `form` tags inside the `<td>` and the it is work !!

```
<td>
  <form action="{{ url('AddComment') }}" method="POST">
    <textarea class="form-control edit" id="com_comment2" name="com_comment2" style="width:90%"  placeholder="Type a New Comment.." required=""></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="com_leads2" value="{{ $leads[0]->LED_CODE }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
    <button id ="afjk" class="btn btn-round btn-success">Submit</button>
  </form>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have one `submit` button to submit a form until you submit it using jquery.

```
<tr>
  <div>
    <form action="{{ url('AddComment') }}" method="POST">
      <div>
      <td>
        <textarea class="form-control edit" id="com_comment2" name="com_comment2" style="width:90%"  placeholder="Type a New Comment.." required=""></textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="com_leads2" value="{{ $leads[0]->LED_CODE }}">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">  // This is SUBMIT button.
      </td>
    </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</tr>
```

Or,
If you want to keep the `<button>` as it is, then you should use jquery/JS function to submit it.

Comment: still the same, nothing happen

Comment: When you click on `submit` button, does the browser refreshes?

Comment: no. nothing happen. not refreshes, no error in console log. but when I do alert, it is work

Comment: alert? Where do you put alert?

Answer (score 0):

add button type too

```
<button id ="af" class="btn btn-round btn-success" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: still the same, nothing happen

Comment: try send csrf too   { csrf_field() }}

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending CSRF token in the form. Please use CSRF token in your form.

```
{ csrf_field() }}
```

Then you need to use

```
<input type="submit"/>
```

for submitting form.If you want to use

```
<button/>
```

to sbumit form,then you have to submit your form using jquery. Your form should look like.

```
<form action="{{ url('AddComment') }}" method="POST">
  { csrf_field() }}
  <div>
    <td>
      <textarea class="form-control edit" id="com_comment2" name="com_comment2" style="width:90%"  placeholder="Type a New Comment.." required=""></textarea>
      <input type="hidden" name="com_leads2" value="{{ $leads[0]->LED_CODE }}">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </td>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check these points:

```
1. Add { csrf_field() }} into your form

2. Change button to input type submit (<input type="submit"/>)

3. Check your modal and find out if all fields are fillable.

4. Print your query and check what sql query has been created.
```

Answer (score 0):

Add CSRF:

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{csrf_token()}}" name="_token" id="token">
```

> OR

```
{!! csrf_field() !!}
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Check `#af` on your JavaScript, maybe you put `preventDefault()` on it. Because if not, every posted answer should have solved your problem by now