# CSS: Force column alignment between cells in different rows

Tags: html, css

I had a 13 column table nicely aligned until I added input fields, which broke  alignment in the column (vertical) direction. Reducing input size to 3vw didn't help, and now the  cells in that row are too small relative to the other rows and cells.

I also tried adding a colSpan to the data cells and headers, but it had no effect.

How can I align the columns of the following table:

```html
<table className={style2}>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colSpan={13}>
        <h3 className={cell_style}>Today: Workout A: TB Stool, TB Rows, DB Incline, Lat Raises
        </h3>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th className={cell_style}>#</th>
      <th colSpan={3} className={cell_style}>TB Stool</th>
      <th colSpan={3} className={cell_style}>TB Rows</th>
      <th colSpan={3} className={cell_style}>DB Incline</th>
      <th colSpan={3} className={cell_style}>Lat Raises</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td className={cell_style}>#</td>

      <td className={cell_style}>Weight</td>
      <td className={cell_style}>Reps</td>
      <td className={cell_style}>Reserve</td>

      <td className={cell_style}>Weight</td>
      <td className={cell_style}>Reps</td>
      <td className={cell_style}>Reserve</td>

      <td className={cell_style}>Weight</td>
      <td className={cell_style}>Reps</td>
      <td className={cell_style}>Reserve</td>

      <td className={cell_style}>Weight</td>
      <td className={cell_style}>Reps</td>
      <td className={cell_style}>Reserve</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <form action="">
        <td className={cell_style} colSpan={1}>#</td>

        <td className={cell_style} colSpan={1}><input type="text" className={input_style} value='50' /></td>
        <td className={cell_style}><input type="text" className={input_style}/>15</td>
        <td className={cell_style}><input type="text" className={input_style}/>0</td>

        <td className={cell_style}><input type="text" className={input_style}/>58</td>
        <td className={cell_style}><input type="text" className={input_style}/>14</td>
        <td className={cell_style}><input type="text" className={input_style}/>2</td>

        <td className={cell_style}><input type="text" className={input_style}/>20</td>
        <td className={cell_style}><input type="text" className={input_style}/>13</td>
        <td className={cell_style}><input type="text" className={input_style}/>1</td>

        <td className={cell_style}><input type="text" className={input_style}/>5</td>
        <td className={cell_style}><input type="text" className={input_style}/>15</td>
        <td className={cell_style}><input type="text" className={input_style}/>0</td>

      </form>
    </tr>

  </tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `form` is not allowed to be a child element of a `table`, `tbody` or `tr`.

You can have an entire table inside a `form`. You can have a `form` inside a table cell. Bu you cannot have part of a table inside a form.

See similar: [Form inside a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967564/form-inside-a-table)

To fix your issue, you will need to wrap your whole table inside the form.

Remove the form from below:

```
<tr>
   <form action="">
   [...]
   </form>
</tr>
```

And wrap your whole table:

```
<form action="">
   <table className={style2}>
   [...]
   </table>
<form>
```

See docs, [HTML form tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp).

Answer (score 0):

you cannot wrap **td** elements inside a **form**. you have to wrap the whole table :

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value="10" class=""></td>
            ....
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

also there is no **className** attribute. you have to use **class=""**

input values should be in the **value** attribute