# Specifying forms in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-blade

I have data which will append to blade view `codes below` and each of them is warped into a form, the issue is data that will send to back-end always comes from first form (somehow other forms data will be ignored).

**How my forms look like:**

[image: one]

**Sending data from first form** `ID = 7`

[image: two]

**Sending data from second form** `Still ID 7`

[image: three]

## Code

```
<script defer>
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $("body").on("click", ".savedynspecto", function(e){
      var form = $(this).closest('form');
      var id = form.find('input[name="product_id"]').val();
      // e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: '{{ url('admin/spacssendto') }}',
        data: {
          '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
          'product_id': id,
          'subspecifications': $(this).closest('form').find('select.subspecifications').val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
          alert('Specifications added successfully.');
        },
        error: function (data) {
          console.log('Error!');
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

`Controller`

```
public function spacssendto(Request $request) {

        $testingdata = $this->validate($request, array(
          'product_id' => 'required',
          'subspecifications' => 'required',
        ));
        $product = Product::find($request->product_id);
        $product->subspecifications()->sync($request->subspecifications, false);

        return response()->json($testingdata);
    }
```

HTML output of my forms

```
<tr>

  <form method="POST" action="http://site.pp/admin/products/15/edit" accept-charset="UTF-8">

  </form>
  <input name="_token" value="DLrcOa0eOm90e4aaGSYp2uCeiuKtbGCT9fCOUP16" type="hidden">

  <input name="product_id" id="product_id" value="15" type="hidden">

  <td>Graphic</td>

  <td>

    <select class="subspecifications form-control tagsselector" id="subspecifications" name="subspecifications[]" multiple="multiple">

      <option value="7">Intel 920</option>

    </select>

  </td>

  <td class="text-center">

    <button type="button" id="savedynspecto" class="savedynspecto btn btn-md btn-success"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Save</button>

  </td>

</tr>
```

**Note:**

What makes me curious is why my form closed right after it opened!

```
<tr>
 <form method="POST" action="http://site.pp/admin/products/15/edit" accept-charset="UTF-8">

  </form>
...
```

here is how my row will append to blade

```
var my_row = $('<tr>');
var my_html = '{{ Form::open() }}<input name="product_id" id="product_id" type="hidden" value="{{$product->id}}"><td>'+value1.title+'</td>';
my_html += '<td><select class="subspecifications form-control tagsselector" id="subspecifications" name="subspecifications[]" multiple="multiple">'+helpers+'</select></td>';
my_html += '<td class="text-center"><button type="button" id="savedynspecto" class="savedynspecto btn btn-md btn-success"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Save</button></td>{{Form::close()}}</tr>';
my_row.html(my_html);
$('#addcustomstr').append(my_row);
```

As you see my `{{ Form::open() }}` is before first `<td>` and `{{Form::close()}}` is right before `</tr>` but why is closing right after it's open?

**Any idea?**

Comment: When is `$('#addcustomstr').append(my_row);` code called? At a glance, you're using `{{ $product->id }}`, which, when loaded from the server will be, let's say 1. If you called `$('#addcustomstr').append(my_row);` multiple times, each `<input>` would have the same value of 1.

Comment: @TimLewis that's right, because the idea was to each form having product id, and in this case all the product id are the same (i am working in edit page)

Comment: Right right. I see that now. On the subject of invalid HTML, you could actually remove your `<form>` elements, add a class to each of your `<tr>`, like `ssWrapper` and target that in your `. savedynspecto` click function; since you're using AJAX, you don't really *need* the form elements there.

Comment: @TimLewis ok, can you give me sample of targeting that class please?

Comment: Change `$(this).closest('form');` to `$(this).closest(".ssWrapper");` :P Just make sure each `<tr>` has `class="ssWrapper"`.

Comment: and what about `csrf_token`? i need that in order to send post request

Comment: @TimLewis I did what you suggested `<td class="ssWrapper">....</td>` still every time i click save only first form will send.

Comment: That says `<td class="ssWrapper">`; I said **<tr>**. Also, you can just use `_token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"` in your JS (assuming you're in `.blade.php` file)

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is malformed. You have an `input` element as a direct descendant of a `tr` element. Only `td` and `th` are allowed as direct descendants of a `tr` element. Put your hidden input field inside the `td` tag, like this:

```
var my_html = '{{ Form::open() }}<td><input name="product_id" id="product_id" type="hidden" value="{{$product->id}}">'+value1.title+'</td>';
```

and check if that works.

EDIT: And that, of course, is also malformed HTML, since the `form` element isn't allowed inside a `tr` element as well. Wrap your whole table inside a form tag instead.

Comment: that wont work bro (if i put my tr inside form) it stopped my data of being append

Comment: The thing is, you can't put a form as a direct descendant of a table or a table row. You either have to put your whole table inside a form, put your form inside a table cell, or don't use tables. Check the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967564/form-inside-a-table

Comment: what if i add another table body and warp tr in that tbody with my form?

Comment: You can't wrap table row elements with a form since a form element can't be a direct descendant of a table element.

Comment: in that case i should only use row class of bootstrap and no way to use table right?

Comment: Yes, that's also an option.

Answer (score 0):

## Solved

Thanks to everyone tried to help, as I was warned that forms are not allowed in `tr` `td` I've decided to use `row` outside of my table and append my data there, in that way i was able to run my forms with no problems.