# Changing text on submit_tag

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, erb

I am working on a sign up application for presentations in Ruby on Rails. As such, I am displaying a list of available presentations, with the last column displaying a button to register for that specific presentation.

```
<table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      # ...
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <% @presentations.each do |pres| %>
      <td scope="row"><%= pres.Name %></td>
      # ...
      <td scope="row">
        <% unless @current_student.Selected == pres.Titel %>
        <%= form_tag students_select_path do %>
          <%= submit_tag "Choose", class: "btn", value: pres.Title %>
        <% end %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like the button to say `"Choose"`, then send off the parameter `pres.Title` to a function that I have defined. For some reason, the button in the table shows the value of `pres.Title`, and not of `"Choose"`. How can this be fixed?

Current working implementation:

```
def addtodb
  @student = Student.find_by(id: session[:student_id])
  if @student.Selected == nil
    prestitle = params[:commit]
    @schueler.update_attribute(:Selected, prestitle)
    redirect_to students_select_path
  end
end
```

Comment: I would go with a JavaScript solution instead. Forms are not supposed to go inside of table rows. You can read more about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967564/form-inside-a-table/5967613

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like the button to say "Choose", then send off the parameter
> pres.Title to a function that I have defined. For some reason, the
> button in the table shows the value of pres.Title, and not of "Choose"
>
> submit_tag(value = "Save changes", options = {}) public

```
<%= submit_tag "Choose", class: "btn", value: pres.Title %>
```

**does not** generates the submit button with text ***Choose*** because you are overriding the value as `pres.Title`. You need to change it to just

```
<%= submit_tag "Choose", class: "btn" %>
```

And you can use `hidden_field_tag` instead for that purpose like so

```
<%= form_tag students_select_path do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'prestitle', pres.Title %>
  <%= submit_tag "Choose", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

Finally, access the value with `params[:prestitle]` in the controller.

**Note:**
As one of the Rails conventions, the **attribute names** should be of **lowercase**. I recommend you to follow it in your app.

Comment: Thank you that worked :). The problem now is that the value comes through like this: `{:value => "(String I need)"}`. Do you know a way to circumvent this issue?

Comment: @EdwardLancaster Can you post the params hash that is appeared in the server log when you click on submit?

Comment: `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"PsyvuDNCpEoSkva4pQcM3xkMe2KUt6m+UV+qkhTJCeIWiV3VmP6jpuu32wK/v/+YLTXt4lgdBSYmQqxaN7I5+g==", "title"=>"{:value=>\"The Future of Cars\"}", "commit"=>"Wählen"}`

Comment: Ok, you can access it with `params[:title][:value]`

Comment: I tried calling that, but then it spits out a type error in my controller, saying "no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer".

Comment: @EdwardLancaster At which line it triggers that error?

Comment: Line 38 in my controller `prestitle = params[:title][:value]`

Comment: @EdwardLancaster Try changing `<%= hidden_field_tag 'prestitle', value: pres.Title %>` to `<%= hidden_field_tag 'prestitle', pres.Title %>`

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem has been completely resolved :)