# form inside a table interaction with POST array

Tags: php, html

Okay my code is not broken, however it can be improved.
I have a form element inside a table, which, according to this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967564/form-inside-a-table)
 is illegal, but for me it is working to some extent.
I am using PHP and the situation is as follows:

Inside that form I have two elements one is `comment` and another is `order_date`;
when I inspect the form in chrome developer tools it shows the correct structure, so the point in the earlier linked post is not happening here. 
When the form gets submitted, I can never get the values of these fields from the post array unless I initialize them first, I am initializing them within a `$_SESSION`, what is weird is that when I initialize them using `$_POST` it also does not work. What is causing this error? Thanks

code for initializing them:

```
if(empty($_SESSION['comment'])) {
    $_SESSION['comment']='';
}
if(empty($_SESSION['order_date'])) {
    $_SESSION['order_date']='';
}
```

code for getting their value after form is submitted:

```
if(isset($_POST['comment']) && isset($_POST['order_date'])) {
    $_SESSION['comment'] = nl2br(filter_var($_POST['comment'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
    $_SESSION['order_date'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['order_date']);
}
```

Trying to get their value in:

```
if(isset($_POST["place_order"])) {
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
}
```

The above code doesn't work

This is the table row of the form:

```
<tr>  
    <td colspan="5" align="center">  
        <form method="POST" action="cart.php" class="form-group">
            <label for="comment">Order comments </label>
            <textarea name="comment" id="comment" class="form-control" 
                      placeholder="Please enter any special instructions for the order" required> 
                          <?php if (isset($_SESSION['comment'])) {
                              echo $_SESSION['comment'];
                          } ?> 
            </textarea> <br>
            <label  for="order_date">Delivery date</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" style="max-width: 20%;" 
                   name="order_date" id="date" required></input> <br />
            <input type="submit" name="place_order" id="place_order" 
                   class="btn logo-green" value="Place Order" />  
        </form> 
    </td> 
</tr>
```

Thank you

Comment: The post you linked to doesn't say that it's illegal to have forms in tables. It says it's illegal to have it directly after a `<table>`, `<tbody>` or `<tr>` tags. You have it inside a `<td>` tag, which is totally fine.

Comment: Fyi, `isset()` can be fed multiple arguments.

Comment: type this `print_r($_POST)` after form submission

Comment: Please don't mysqli escape when storing in your session.   In fact, I recommend prepared statements when you are querying with submitted data.

Comment: @ZainFarooq This gives an empty array lol literally gives array()

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thank you for the clarification I thought the form being a child of a table was not allowed.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thank you, I did not know isset can have multiple arguments.

Comment: You have made two tags for `input` here `<input type="date" class="form-control" style="max-width: 20%;" 
 name="order_date" id="date" required></input>`

Comment: It should be like `<input type="date" class="form-control" style="max-width: 20%;" name="order_date" id="date" required>`

Comment: Do you receive value of `$_SESSION` _inside_ form

Comment: @ZainFarooq You're right about the input part, it's the same for the textarea, too, however tried removing it and I still get the same problem. And yes I do receive the value in $_SESSION but not if I use $_POST or a normal variable like $order_date

Comment: No `textarea` is correct

Comment: Ok write `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` just after `php` starting tag and tell what happens there

Comment: @ZainFarooq it just says that the variables are unidentified when I try to echo them and the print_r($_POST) still the same. empty Array(). That's why it's so confusing it's like they get passed, but not really passed...

Comment: Ok, change the names of variables which are in session

Comment: Like for `$comment` change it to anything else