# copy the tracking id from Table 2's column to Table 1's column

Tags: php, mysql, forms

In below image , Once we click on "**submit**" button in third column , I want to copy the tracking id from **Table 2's column** to **Table 1's column**....

Table **orders**

[image]

displayed tracking id" in 4th column

[image]

I saved order information in table **orders** [ Table 1 ]

[image]

I saved tracking ids in table **awbno** [ Table 2 ] & in column **tracking_two**

[image]

**track.php**

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","do_management4");

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM orders");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>order</th>
<th>payment</th>
<th>generate</th>
<th>tracking id</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$id = $row['id'];
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['order_id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['payment_type'] . "</td>";

    echo "<td>";
    if (empty($row['tracking_one'])) {
        echo "<form method='post' action='call.php'>";
        echo "<input type ='hidden' name='id' value='$id'>
          <input type='submit'>
          </form>";
    }
    echo "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['tracking_one'] . "</td>";

echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

**call.php**

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","do_management4");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM orders");

$id = $_POST['id']; 
$r = ""; 

$sql = $con->query("update orders set tracking_one = '$r' WHERE id ='$id'");
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

I did't found any particular query in google, What query will help me ?

Comment: `$r` is an empty string the update statement set `tracking_one` to empty

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Thanks for reply, yes, i am not getting what query to post, i kept it empty......

Comment: How come you don't perform a JOIN on the tables so you don't need to click the generate button in the first place?

Comment: @MatthiasBö Thanks for reply, we have 100 rows in `table2` & 10 rows in `table1`..... is there any other way ?

Comment: Side note: `<form>` cannot be made a child of `<table>`.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Thanks for reply , means if i use <form> inside <table> will not work in my case ? I dont know much about this..... but i used `$r` to generate random numbers before & it worked fine for me, or did i misunderstood your statement ?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5967613/1415724) in another question explains it.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Thanks for the link, i will check it....

Comment: Welcome. That could be contributing to the problem. Look at your HTML source and you can see what is being populated (or not) and how. If something fails, enable error reporting and error checking on the query. What you're trying to pull in for data in the form, is probably a GET method for the id rather than POST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should be something like this

```
$sql = $con->query("update orders set tracking_one = (select tracking_two from awbno WHERE id =$id)");
```

Comment: Thanks , I tried like `$sql = $con->query("update orders set tracking_one = select tracking_two from awbno WHERE id ='$id' ");` , is it correct ? because i  got result as [link](http://sbdev1.kidsdial.com/ecom1/ekart/track.php)

Comment: yes, you can check which id you are sending. If that transaction id is updated then query is working fine

Comment: means like this : `$sql = $con->query("update orders set tracking_one = select tracking_two from awbno WHERE id =1 ");`  ?

Comment: yes check id = 1 in table awbno which transaction id you see their
same should be updated in orders table

Comment: I tried that code, but i got same result as before [here](http://sbdev1.kidsdial.com/ecom1/ekart/track.php) , also as i mentioned in question, there is `tracking id : 14105818000000` for id :1 in `awb table`.... but still i got same result....

Comment: Or is it possible to do other way ? means once we click on button , copy the values present in `table 1- orders` to `table 2 - awbno`....

Comment: id field in order and id field in awb table has any relation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183935/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-yash-fatnani).

Comment: Then how do both tables relate each other?
which value is to updated in table 1