# Dynamic form not posting new elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to adapt an static existing form that is inside of a table, to be dynamic in certain cases depending on "select".

What I've done is create new TR's TD's on the existing table id -> "peticionobras" and fill them using innerHtml with the new input text I need. Everything in plain javascript as follows:

```
//if select is...

if (value == "A" || value == "B" || value == "C"){

            var tableObras = document.getElementById("peticionobras");
            if (tableObras.rows[5].cells[0].innerHTML.includes("Codigo_Emp_Actuacion")){
                var row = tableObras.insertRow(5);
                var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                cell1.innerHTML = "<dd><b>C_Emp_con_necesidad</b>:";
                cell2.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='C_Emp_con_necesidad' name='C_Emp_con_necesidad'>&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><br><bdi id='C_Emp_con_necesidad_tag'>Emplazamiento con problemas potencialmente solucionables con la implantaci\u00F3n</bdi><br><br>";
                document.getElementById("C_Emp_con_necesidad").setAttribute("required", true);

                var row = tableObras.insertRow(6);
                var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                cell1.innerHTML = "<dd><b>D_Emp_con_necesidad</b>:";
                cell2.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='D_Emp_con_necesidad' name='D_Emp_con_necesidad'>&nbsp;&nbsp;<bdi id='D_Emp_con_necesidad_tag'></bdi>";
                document.getElementById("D_Emp_con_necesidad").setAttribute("required", true);

                var row = tableObras.insertRow(9);
                var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                cell1.innerHTML = "<dd><b>Direccion_coordenadas</b>:";
                cell1.id = "testtdtd";
                cell2.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='Direccion_coordenadas' name='Direccion_coordenadas'>&nbsp;&nbsp;<bdi id='Direccion_coordenadas_tag'></bdi>";
                document.getElementById("Direccion_coordenadas").setAttribute("required", true);

            }
        }
```

The result in terms of aspect is fine, it puts what I need where it should be. But the behaviour is not correct. The new required field they don't appear as required, and once you submit the form the new inputs are not submitted

> (Notice: Undefined index: D_Emp_con_necesidad in...).

The main page code is schematically as follows:

```
<table id="peticionobras">
    <tbody>
    <form action="./test.php" method="POST">
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>6</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>7</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>8</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>9</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>10</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td><button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button></td><td>2</td></tr>
    </form>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I think the way I implemented it is too much straigthforward. 
Any suggestion in how to add new inputs in the existing form `id='obras'` inside the table `id='peticionobras'` in the positions 5, 6 and 9 or any clue to follow, it would be highly appreciatted.

Thanks
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*EDITED [as @QUENTIN explained in the following question: 
[Form inside a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967564/form-inside-a-table)
*--A form is not allowed to be a child element of a table, tbody or tr--*

```
<form action="./test.php" method="POST">
<table id="peticionobras">
    <tbody>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>6</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>7</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>8</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>9</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>10</td><td>2</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<button type="submit" value="submit">
    Submit
</button>
</form>
<script>
var value  = 'A';
if (value == "A" || value == "B" || value == "C"){
        var tableObras = document.getElementById("peticionobras");
        if (tableObras.rows[5].cells[0].innerHTML.includes("Codigo_Emp_Actuacion")){
            var row = tableObras.insertRow(5);
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            cell1.innerHTML = "<dd><b>C_Emp_con_necesidad</b>:";
            cell2.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='C_Emp_con_necesidad' name='C_Emp_con_necesidad'>&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><br><bdi id='C_Emp_con_necesidad_tag'>Emplazamiento con problemas potencialmente solucionables con la implantaci\u00F3n</bdi><br><br>";
            document.getElementById("C_Emp_con_necesidad").setAttribute("required", true);

            var row = tableObras.insertRow(6);
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            cell1.innerHTML = "<dd><b>D_Emp_con_necesidad</b>:";
            cell2.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='D_Emp_con_necesidad' name='D_Emp_con_necesidad'>&nbsp;&nbsp;<bdi id='D_Emp_con_necesidad_tag'></bdi>";
            document.getElementById("D_Emp_con_necesidad").setAttribute("required", true);

            var row = tableObras.insertRow(9);
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            cell1.innerHTML = "<dd><b>Direccion_coordenadas</b>:";
            cell1.id = "testtdtd";
            cell2.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='Direccion_coordenadas' name='Direccion_coordenadas'>&nbsp;&nbsp;<bdi id='Direccion_coordenadas_tag'></bdi>";
            document.getElementById("Direccion_coordenadas").setAttribute("required", true);

        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, actually the new fields input type text are already created inside the form within the table using innerHtml.
Thanks

Comment: Can you give the code for it. Since by on your example code. adding the form should fix the problem. User can submit the form without will the field.

Comment: The form is implemented on the main page, and it's not the issue. The problem is that the new fileds added with the javascript code I've copied are not posted once the submit is done. 
As I mentioned the new fields are created within the existing form already.

What I gues is that the index of the form are not updated with the innerHTML trick I've done and thus the new fields are not posted. Of that I'm not sure.

Regards

Comment: After putting the form definition wraping the entire table and not the table wrapping the form. The code started working as expected. I should have posted the form as you mentioned. I will accept your answer since it pointed me towards the right direction. Thanks