# Ajax form not working when forms are added dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to create **posts** and dynamically generate **update** forms in the index action. But the forms that are dynamically generated update form are not working. Please find the code below:

**posts_controller.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.save
  end

  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content)
  end
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<h4>Posts</h4>
<table class="table table-bordered table-posts">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Content</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% if @posts.present? %>
      <% @posts.each do |post| %>
        <%= render "posts/table_row", post: post %>
      <% end %>
    <% else %>
      <tr class="no-posts-found">
        <td colspan="4" style='text-align: center'>
          No posts found.
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<h4>Create Post</h4>
<%= form_for Post.new, url: posts_path, method: :post, html: { remote: true }  do |f| %>
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control", required: true %></td>
        <td>
          <%= f.text_field :content, class: "form-control", required: true %> 
        </td>
        <td><%= f.submit "Add" %></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
<% end %>
```

**_table_row.html.erb**

```
<tr class="post-<%= post.id %>">
  <%= form_for post, url: posts_path(post), method: :patch, html: { remote: true }  do |f| %>
    <td><%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control", required: true %></td>
    <td>
      <%= f.text_field :content, class: "form-control", required: true %> 
    </td>
    <td>
      <%= f.submit "Update" %>
    </td>
  <% end %>
</tr>
```

**create.js.erb**

```
$("table.table-posts").find("tbody").append("<%= j(render 'posts/table_row', post: @post) %>")
```

**update.js.erb**

```
alert("Updated")
```

Comment: You used the `@post` variable for path in `index.html.erb` but you did not define the `@post` variable in `index` action.

Comment: If you are going to create a new post form, you need to add the `@post = Post.new` to index action.

Comment: @demir - Thanks for pointing it out. Between this is not my actual project code. Missed it when I tried to mask project-specific code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A form is not allowed to be a child element of a table, tbody or tr. Attempting to put one there will tend to cause the browser to move the form to it appears after the table (while leaving its contents — table rows, table cells, inputs, etc — behind). Ref - https://stackoverflow.com/a/5967613/3185510

Moving the form inside the `<td>` tag fixed the issue.

**_table_row.html.erb**

```
<tr class="post-<%= post.id %>">
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td>
    <%= form_for post, url: posts_path(post), method: :patch, html: { remote: true }  do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control", required: true %>
      <%= f.text_field :content, class: "form-control", required: true %>
      <%= f.submit "Update" %>
    <% end %>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update create action for js response.

```
def create
  ..
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

Comment: Create is working perfectly. The issue is with the update action.

Comment: There are many posts.  which post will have update form? Are there  both create form and update form?

Comment: There are multiple 'update' forms (an 'update' form for each post) and a single create form. Anyways, I was able to fix the issue. Please find my answer below. Thank you!