# Nodejs Deleting row on button press using body-parser

Tags: javascript, node.js, body-parser

Have a call being made to a database and generating a table. I want it so I can use body-parser to know what the id / value / name is of the button I clicked that will correspond to  the database entry I want to delete. Is there a way to do that using the form or will I have to add a javascript click handler to each button with the id?

```
<form action="/deleteQuestion" method="POST">
    <tbody>
        <% results.forEach(function(r) { %>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">
                    <%= r.Id %>
                </th>
                <td>
                    <%= r.Question %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%= r.Answer %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%= r.Wrong1 %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%= r.Wrong2 %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%= r.Wrong3 %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button value=<%=r.Id %> name="Delete">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <% }); %>
    </tbody>
</form>
```

---

nodejs file

```
app.post('/deleteQuestion', async(req, res) => {
    //Won't work the way I want it to    
    const question = req.body.Delete   
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some pretty hacky stuff but this seems to work the way I was hoping. if anyone knows the proper way I'd love to see a link / guide.

--EDIT

After a couple days I think this is the correct way to go about adding even handlers to buttons (I forgot about onclick events)

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function sendData(id) {
            $.post('deleteQuestion/' + id)
        }
    </script>
</head> 

<tbody>
    <% results.forEach(function(r) { %>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">
                <%= r.Id %>
            </th>
            <td>
                <%= r.Question %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= r.Answer %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= r.Wrong1 %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= r.Wrong2 %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= r.Wrong3 %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="submit" onclick="sendData(<%=r.Id %>)" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <% }); %>
</tbody>
```

---

```
app.post('/deleteQuestion/:id', async(req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params.id);   })
```

Comment: Interesting enough due to how data tables work it seems the javascript is not added to every button. It only adds to the initially shown elements. I'm sure there is an onChange event that can be used

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap the table row instead of the whole tbody,
then add the `Id` as parameter

```
<tbody>
    <% results.forEach(function(r) { %>
        <form action="/deleteQuestion/"+<%= r.Id %>  method="POST">
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">
                    <%= r.Id %>
                </th>
                <td>
                    <%= r.Question %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%= r.Answer %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%= r.Wrong1 %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%= r.Wrong2 %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%= r.Wrong3 %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button value=<%=r.Id %> name="Delete">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </form>
    <% }); %>
</tbody>
```

then handle it in node with

```
app.post('/deleteQuestion/:id', async(req, res) => {
    // do the delete here using the id
})
```

Comment: Hmm the submit button doesn't seem to trigger the form. This table is being converted to a datatable, I wonder if that might cause problems.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967564/form-inside-a-table
Well that isn't fair

Comment: @Ubarjohade thanks for pointing it out. i guest he could just bind a click event that will pass the id and trigger a XHR request.