# checkboxes won't submit even when checked

Tags: html

As you can see here, I have the code for checkboxes to modify admin permissions. However, the checkboxes aren't being sent to the server even when they are checked. I can't understand why this is happening. Only the hidden input and the csrf_token is being sent when the submit button is clicked.

```
<tbody>
                {% for profile in admins %}
                    <tr>
                    <td>{{ profile.player.guid }}</td>
                    <td>{{ profile.user.username }}</td>
                    <form method="post">
                        {% with permissions=profile.admin_permissions_as_list %}
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="modify,{{ profile.user }}">
                            <td style="text-align: center"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="ban" {% if permissions.0 == '1' %}checked="checked"{% endif %}></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="unban" {% if permissions.1 == '1' %}checked="checked"{% endif %}></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="checkplayers" {% if permissions.2 == '1' %}checked="checked"{% endif %}></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="viewlog" {% if permissions.3 == '1' %}checked="checked"{% endif %}></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="key" {% if permissions.4 == '1' %}checked="checked"{% endif %}></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="faction" {% if permissions.5 == '1' %}checked="checked"{% endif %}></td>
                            <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary">修改权限</button></td>
                        {% endwith %}
                    </form>
                    <td>
                        <form method="post">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="remove,{{ profile.user }}">
                            <button type="submit" onclick="return confirmRemove('{{ profile.user.username }}');" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger">取消权限</button>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
```

Comment: Your checkboxes need a `name` attribute...

Comment: Since when `<form>` is a valid child of `<tr>` ? Wrap it in `<td>`.

Comment: Thanks, name seemed to be what I needed! I thought it would be value lol since a lot of the examples used values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two major problems.

- [A form can't be a parent element of a `<td>` (or a child element of a `<tr>`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967564/form-inside-a-table/5967613#5967613)
- A control can't send its `name=value` data if it doesn't have a name (and your checkboxes all lack names)

Comment: Thanks, name seemed to be what I needed! I thought it would be value lol since a lot of the examples used values.

Comment: @hi126136 — The `name=value` pair needs a name **and** a value (although checkboxes will use a default value of On)