# Post form not submitting inside while loop table php

Tags: php, html

I am trying to submit this form but it only submits the hidden input field. I can't understand why. It was working before.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($gettimesheets)) {
    $date = $row['Date'];
    $date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date));
    $teachername = $row['StaffName'];
    $teacherid = $row['StaffID'];
    $starttime = $row['StartTime'];
    $endtime = $row['EndTime'];
    $totalhours = $row['TotalHours'];
    $timesheetid = $row['id'];

    ?>
    <tr>
        <form action="edittimesheet.php" method="post">
            <td class="text-center"><?php echo $date; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $teachername; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $teacherid; ?></td>
            <td><input type="time" name="starttime" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $starttime; ?>"></td>
            <td><input type="time" name="endtime" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $endtime; ?>">
                <input type="text" name="timesheetid" value="<?php echo $timesheetid; ?>" hidden></td>
            <td class="text-right">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Edit"/>
                <a href="deletetimesheet.php?id=<?php echo $timesheetid; ?>"
                   class="btn btn-simple btn-danger">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </form>
    </tr>

    <?php
}
```

Comment: You have a few syntax errors like `echo $date ;`

Comment: type="time" is not supported by all browsers. try type="text"

Comment: @db1975 ive tried that but didnt make a difference

Comment: @ObsidianAge What is wrong with the syntax? if its the ; i've moved it but no difference

Comment: can you show your edittimesheet.php ?

what ist the result, if you type 

print_r($_POST);

in your edittimesheet.php

Comment: @db1975 Array ( [timesheetid] => 1 )

Comment: What changed since it last worked? That's what you'd have to find. Did you make a copy of it or did you overwrite it all?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner The code hasen't been changed. For some reason its not submitting the input fields when its in a table, but when its not in a table anymore, its fine again.

Comment: There's code missing then. I don't see the `<table></table>` tags in your post and if you have them  outside of `<form></form>`, you can't do that. `<form>` cannot be made a child of `<table>`.

Answer (score 1):

It's odd but putting parts of a table inside a form is not a good idea. Actually browsers in such situation are confused! You can put your whole form inside a cell (td).

For more information [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967564/form-inside-a-table)

Answer (score 0):

Make your form outside your table and on your edit-submit button the id you edit.

```
<form action="edittimesheet.php"     
<table>
<?php 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($gettimesheets)) {
     $date = $row['Date'];
     $date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date));
     $teachername = $row['StaffName'];
     $teacherid = $row['StaffID'];
     $starttime = $row['StartTime'];
     $endtime = $row['EndTime'];
     $totalhours = $row['TotalHours'];
     $timesheetid = $row['id'];

                                                ?>
                                                <tr>
method="post">
                                                  <td class="text-center"><?php echo $date ;?></td>
                                                  <td><?php echo $teachername ;?></td>
                                                  <td><?php echo $teacherid ;?></td>
                                                  <td><input type="time" name="starttime[$timesheetid]" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $starttime; ?>" ></td>
                                                  <td><input type="time" name="endtime[$timesheetid]" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $endtime; ?>" >
                                                  <input type="text" name="timesheetid[$timesheetid]" value="<?php echo $timesheetid; ?>" hidden></td>
                                                  <td class="text-right">
                                                    <input type="submit" name="edit" value ="<?php echo $timesheetid; ?>;" class="btn btn-success" value="Edit"/>
                                                    <a href="deletetimesheet.php?id=<?php echo $timesheetid; ?>" class="btn btn-simple btn-danger">Delete</a>
                                                  </td>

                                                </tr>

                                                <?php
                                              }
?>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: you can than each your variables with 
$editid = $_POST['edit'];

$_POST['starttime'][$editid]

Comment: that only submits the last row of the table.

Comment: look at the name of inputs:  name="starttime[$timesheetid]"

Comment: yeah that just submitted alot more information than needed to be submitted.

Comment: yes now use $editid = $_POST['edit']; AND $starttime = $_POST['starttime'][$editid];