# Submit Form Using AJAX `onKeyUp` In Each <tr> Row Of A Table In Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms, this

I have a table full of rows that have `<form>` tag inside them and have `<input>` tags inside cells as shown in the below markup.

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <form>
    <td><input onkeyup="return searchGet(this.parentNode.parentNode)" type="text" name="Firstname"/></td>
    <td><input onkeyup="return searchGet(this.parentNode.parentNode)" type="text" name="Lastname"/></td>
    <td><input onkeyup="return searchGet(this.parentNode.parentNode)" type="number" name="Age"/></td>
   </form>      
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <form>
    <td><input onkeyup="return searchGet(this.parentNode.parentNode)" type="text" name="Firstname"/></td>
    <td><input onkeyup="return searchGet(this.parentNode.parentNode)" type="text" name="Lastname"/></td>
    <td><input onkeyup="return searchGet(this.parentNode.parentNode)" type="number" name="Age"/></td>
   </form>      
  </tr>
........
</table>
```

Now I want to submit the each row form using pure Vanilla JavaScript Ajax function whenever anyone types in the input tags to their respective form. My Ajax function is simple that is getting the Form Object to pick all form elements value whenever wee type in any element.

```
function searchGet(incomingForm) {
    var FD = new FormData(incomingForm);    
    var ajx = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajx.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (ajx.readyState == 4 && ajx.status == 200) {
            console.log(ajx.responseText);
        }
    };
    ajx.open("POST", "submit.php", true);
    ajx.send(FD);
    return false;
}
```

Now the problem is that `this.parentNode.parentNode` is not picking `<FORM>` element but it's directly picking `<TR>` element. So how can I make it working perfectly?

**Note:** I tried many other ways but not able to make it like...

- `this.parentElement.parentElement`
- `this.parentNode.parentNode`
- `this.closest(form)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967564/form-inside-a-table), you can't place forms between `tr` elements. The solution is restyle to resemble a table. Also, use `addEventListener` to have a more elegant code.

```js
document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function(ev) {
  if (ev.target.tagName == "INPUT") {
    console.log(ev.target.closest("form").id);
  }
});
```

```css
div { display: inline-block; width: 100px; }
input {width: 95px; }
```

```html
<div>Firstname</div>
<div>Lastname</div>
<div>Age</div>
<form id="first">
  <div><input type="text" name="Firstname" /></div>
  <div><input type="text" name="Lastname" /></div>
  <div><input type="number" name="Age" /></div>
</form>
<form id="second">
  <div><input type="text" name="Firstname" /></div>
  <div><input type="text" name="Lastname" /></div>
  <div><input type="number" name="Age" /></div>
</form>
```