# Form submit doesn't work at all inside foreach loop

Tags: html, laravel, forms, loops, submit

The button doesn't do anything at all. It works if I make a form with submit inside each <td tag, but obviously I don't wanna do that since then you can't read all the values.
I just wanna have 1 submit button, for some reason that breaks it. *facepalm*

Came across few similar topics but none of them quite had any solution I was looking for.

html:

```html
<table class="table table-hover">
    @foreach ($query as $x)
        <tr class="table-dark">
            <form method="post" action="{{ action('Controller@admin_changeinfo') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>

                <th scope="row">User#{{$x->user_id}}</th>
                <td>{{$x->name}}</td>

                <td>
                    <input name="target" type="hidden" value="{{$x->user_id}}"/>
                    <input name="name" type="hidden" value="{{$x->name}}"/>

                    <input name="email" type="text" class="form-control" 
                    id="admin_place_em" value="{{$x->email}}" placeholder="{{$x->email}}">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="role" class="custom-select" id="admin_role_change">
                        <option selected="" value={{$x->role}}>{{$role_ar[$x->role]}}</option>
                        <option value="1" class="admin_role_opt">Value 1</option>
                        <option value="2" class="admin_role_opt">Value 2</option>
                        <option value="0" class="admin_role_opt">Value 0</option>
                        <option value="3" class="admin_role_opt">Value 3</option>
                    </select>
                </td>  

                <td>
                    <input name="" type="submit" value="Update" href="/admin" class="btn btn-default">
                </td>

            </form>     
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    {{$query->links()}}
</table>
```

And here is the route if that's any help:
`Route::post('/admin','Controller@admin_changeinfo');`

--

EDIT:
Apparently, you can't have a [Form inside a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967564/form-inside-a-table) .

Solution: Put the whole table inside the form. Create a button with an unique value, make the other fields unique as well:

```html
<button name="submit" type="submit" value={{$x->user_id}} href="/admin" class="btn btn-default">
Update
</button>
```

In your controller:

```php
$pressed = $request->submit;

$this -> validate($request, [
    'email'.$pressed => 'required',
    'role'.$pressed => 'required|in:1,2,3,0'
]);

$name = $request -> input('name'. $pressed);
$target = $request -> input('target'. $pressed);

return 'submit called: '.$name.' '.$target;
```

Fixed version:

```html
<form method="post" action="{{ action('Controller@admin_changeinfo') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>

    <table class="table table-hover">
        @foreach ($query as $x)
            <tr class="table-dark">
            
                <th scope="row">User#{{$x->user_id}}</th>
                <td>{{$x->name}}</td>

                <td>
                    <input name="target{{$x->user_id}}" type="hidden" value="{{$x->user_id}}"/>
                    <input name="name{{$x->user_id}}" type="hidden" value="{{$x->name}}"/>

                    <input name="email{{$x->user_id}}" type="text" class="form-control" 
                    id="admin_place_em" value="{{$x->email}}" placeholder="{{$x->email}}"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="role{{$x->user_id}}" class="custom-select" id="admin_role_change">
                        <option selected="" value={{$x->role}}>{{$role_ar[$x->role]}}</option>
                        <option value="1" class="admin_role_opt">Value 1</option>
                        <option value="2" class="admin_role_opt">Value 2</option>
                        <option value="0" class="admin_role_opt">Value 0</option>
                        <option value="3" class="admin_role_opt">Value 3</option>
                    </select>
                </td>  

                <td>
                    <button name="submit" type="submit" value={{$x->user_id}} href="/admin" class="btn btn-default">
                        Update
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>

        @endforeach
        {{$query->links()}}
    </table>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

1- change this

```
<input name="" type="submit" value="Update" href="/admin" class="btn btn-default">
```

to this

```
<button type="submit">Update</button>
```

2- change this

```
Route::post('/admin','Controller@admin_changeinfo');
```

to this:

```
Route::post('/admin', ['as' => 'admin.changeinfo',
    'uses' => 'Controller@admin_changeinfo'] );
```

3- change this:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ action('Controller@admin_changeinfo') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

to this:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['admin.changeinfo'],
                     'method' => 'post',
                     'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}
```