# Rails 6.1 Link submit_tag to form_with

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have an html table where the table rows are generated through a partial. The partial is wrapped in a form_with so I can delete multiple records with checkboxes. The issue is I want my button_tag outside of the form_with block. Is it possible to link the button_tag to the form so it doesn't have to be positioned inside the form block?

A dropdown action menu

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="actionMenuToggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Actions</button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="actionMenu">
    <li><%= button_tag "Delete Selected2", class: "btn btn-link dropdown-item", data: { action: "form-submission#destroyMultiple" } %></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I then code my table skeleton as normal and my rows render the following partial

```
<%= render partial: "client_table", clients: @clients %>
```

and in that partial I have my form_with tag and loop to iterate through clients

```
<tbody id="clients">
<%= form_with(url: destroy_multiple_clients_path, data: { controller: 'form-submission', form_submission_target: "delete_multiple_form" }) do |form| %>
  <% @clients.each do |client| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= check_box_tag("client_ids[]", client.id, false, { class: "form-check-input", onclick: "onClientSelect();" }) %></td>
      <td><%= client.id %></td>
      <td><%= client.name %></td>
      <td><%= client.city %></td>
      <td><%= client.state_province %></td>
      <td><%= client.postal_code %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_client_path(client), class: "btn btn-success edit_client" %> </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

just add `form: 'id_of_form'` to the submit tag then put an id on `form_with .... id:'id_of_form'`

Answer (score -1):

A form cannot be a child of a [table, tbody or tr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967564/form-inside-a-table).

So you'll need to wrap the entire table in a `form_with` block. If that's the case, it's potentially easier to have your button be included within the form, simply wrap the table and table header elements in the form.

(also note, however, that you cannot nest form objects)