# HTML - input field jumps out of html table

Tags: php, html, input, html-table

I have a 'dynamic' table where someone can change info about a person. When clicking on 'update' the cell should change to an input field. This works, but somehow the input field jumps out of the table and sits above it.

This is part of the function that shows the table:

```
 echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td><b>' . ucfirst(htmlspecialchars($data)) . '</b></td>'; 
        if($url_param_index[1] == $info) // Checks if second url-parameter is same as $info on row that is clicked on and changes cell to form input field
        {       
            echo '<form action="update.php method="POST"';                  
            echo '<td><input type="text" name="' . $data . '" value="' . $info . '"></td>';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="lidnummer" value="' . $gegevens_lid['lidnummer'] . '">';
            echo '<td><button type="submit">Save</button></td>';
            echo '<td>----</td>';
            echo '</form>';
        }
        else
        {
            if($data == 'lidnummer' || $data == 'adres' || $data == 'woonplaats')
            {
                echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($info) . '</td>';
                echo '<td> ---- </td>';
                echo '<td> ---- </td>';
                
            } 
            else
            {
                echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($info) . '</td>';
                echo '<td><a href="lid.php?lidnummer=' . $gegevens_lid['lidnummer'] . '&' . $data . '=' . $info . '">Update</td>';
                echo '<td> ---- </td>';
            }            
        }
        echo '</tr>';
```

This is the page where the function gets called to show the table:

```
<div>
    <h3>Lid:</h3>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Info</th>
                <th>Pas aan</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
            <?php show_single_lid($conn, $lidnummer); ?>          
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Before clicking update**
[image: Before clicking update]

**After clicking update**
[image: After clicking update]

The input field should stay in the table at the same row/column, but it jumps out and the rest slides one over...

Comment: please provide the javascript code also

Comment: There is no javascript here going on :p

Comment: `echo '<form action="update.php method="POST"'; ` is missing a `>` to close the `<form>` tag. Donno if this is causing the issue, but try to tide up the code before submitting here :)

Comment: Also, make sure you only include `<td>` elements as direct children of `<tr>`. Placing a `<form>` as a direct child of `<tr>` might cause issues...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try changing your PHP code to this.

```php
 echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td><b>' . ucfirst(htmlspecialchars($data)) . '</b></td>'; 
        if($url_param_index[1] == $info) // Checks if second url-parameter is same as $info on row that is clicked on and changes cell to form input field
        {       
            echo '<td><form action="update.php method="POST"';                  
            echo '<td><input type="text" name="' . $data . '" value="' . $info . '"></td>';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="lidnummer" value="' . $gegevens_lid['lidnummer'] . '">';
            echo '<td><button type="submit">Save</button></td>';
            echo '<td>----</td>';
            echo '</form></td>';
        }
        else
        {
            if($data == 'lidnummer' || $data == 'adres' || $data == 'woonplaats')
            {
                echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($info) . '</td>';
                echo '<td> ---- </td>';
                echo '<td> ---- </td>';
                
            } 
            else
            {
                echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($info) . '</td>';
                echo '<td><a href="lid.php?lidnummer=' . $gegevens_lid['lidnummer'] . '&' . $data . '=' . $info . '">Update</td>';
                echo '<td> ---- </td>';
            }            
        }
        echo '</tr>';
```

Comment: That seems to work, but I can't really tell why. As far as I can tell you only added a td tag before <form> and </td> after </form> and it works. Can you explain?

Comment: `td` tags are used as table columns.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: Also make sure to mark this as the answer

Comment: @Xavvey you can not nest a form into a table like you tried to do. Either the form element has to go around the _whole_ table, or it needs to be contained within a single table cell. Anything else is invalid HTML, and the browser will built a different DOM than the one you want out of that, when it applies error correction.

Comment: (Which means the "solution" presented here is still not actually correct.)

Comment: @CBroe Thanks! A little weird though because I got this idea from a youtube vid and there it seemed to work. I also got it to work before on another page but scrapped that for something else and now it did not work... But I'll just go with this!

Comment: `<form` is still missing its closing `>` and `</form></td>` requires an opening `<td>`

Answer (score 0):

form is not permitted inside table or tr tags. So your form should encompas whole table or be in a single cell.

For example (note the form is inside single cell):

```
echo '<td><form action="update.php" method="POST">';                  
echo '<input type="text" name="' . $data . '" value="' . $info . '">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="lidnummer" value="' . $gegevens_lid['lidnummer'] . '"><button type="submit">Save</button></form></td>';
echo '<td></td>';
echo '<td>----</td>';
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/5967613/13891891

Comment: Well, here the 'save' button jumps to the cell containing the input field and in the 'solution' above it does not but still works. Why should I go for this?