# How to structure tags for a table where each row is a form?

Tags: html

I have to create a page with a table, where each row of data is modifiable and can be saved directly by editing the table (think of something like what [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) does to allow you to edit a table inline). I have several options before me and I am wondering which is the more semantically correct:

- Create a giant `<form>` wrapping my `<table>` where each row containing several `<input>`s is a child of the same giant `<form>`
- Create a `<table>` where each row is a separate `<form>`

I would be linking every `<input>` to a Javascript callback so that the updates are sent to the server automatically every time you change a row. Which route is most in line with the HTML 5 specs?

Comment: You are not the first one to have this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035966/create-a-html-table-where-each-tr-is-a-form

Comment: @Boldewyn Ah I knew it but I failed in my Googling efforts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Create a giant `<form>` wrapping my `<table>` where each row containing several `<input>`s is a child of the same giant `<form>`

That is allowed

> Create a `<table>` where each row is a separate `<form>`

That is not allowed

> I would be linking every `<input>` to a Javascript callback so that the updates are sent to the server automatically every time you change a row.

That doesn't, technically, require a form at all. You should still have one though so that you can use progressive enhancement and not depend on the JS functioning. Give each form control a row id as part of the name so you can tell which row the data belongs to when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You can't wrap each row in a form, it's not valid syntax. You can either have a form in each cell (which is a pain) or wrap the whole thing in a form, which is the preferred way for most people.

Another alternative is to do what PHPMyAdmin does, have no forms at all and use Ajax.