# create form in html table row in cakephp view

Tags: php, html, cakephp, cakephp-2.7

I am trying to create **form** inside table td in **foreach loop** of cakePHP, I want to form in only 3 table **td** and update it in. Also, it is working fine but only issue is with alignment of heading because of form inside **td**. If I take out form out pf td, it doesn't work

```
<table class="table table-hover ">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Customer</th>
    <th>Dress</th>
    <th>Order Date</th>
    <th>Delivery Date</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Tailor</th>
    <th>Tailor Cost</th>
    <th class="actions"><?php echo __('Actions'); ?></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($orders as $order): ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link($order['Customer']['name'], array('controller' => 'customers', 'action' => 'view', $order['Customer']['id'])); ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link($order['Dress']['type'], array('controller' => 'dresses', 'action' => 'view', $order['Dress']['id'])); ?>
        </td>
        <td><?php echo h(date('d-M-y',strtotime($order['Order']['order_date']))); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h(date('d-M-y',strtotime($order['Order']['delivery_date']))); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($status[$order['Order']['status']]); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        **<td>
            <?php echo $this->Form->create('Order',['class'=>'form-inline']); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('id', ['type'=>'hidden','value'=>$order['Order']['id']]); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('user_id', ['empty'=>'--Select--','options'=>$users, 'selected'=>$order['User']['id'], 'div' => false, 'label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control']); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('tailor_price', ['value' =>$order['Order']['tailor_price'], 'div' => false, 'label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control','style'=>'max-width:140px;']); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->button(__('Update'), ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
        </td>**
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

But it's breaking the table th and td alignment :

[image]

Please help me out. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: You used 8 columns in table header, but in table body you used only 6 - this is reason why it's not aligned.  I think you should not use table element here - take a look at this question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035966/create-a-html-table-where-each-tr-is-a-form

Comment: @Szymon's comment is the correct answer, the ones currently given below do produce invalid HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Order',['class'=>'form-inline']); ?>
   <td>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link($order['Customer']['name'], array('controller' => 'customers', 'action' => 'view', $order['Customer']['id'])); ?>
        </td>
   <td>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link($order['Dress']['type'], array('controller' => 'dresses', 'action' => 'view', $order['Dress']['id'])); ?>
  </td>
  <td><?php echo h(date('d-M-y',strtotime($order['Order']['order_date']))); ?>&nbsp;</td>
  <td><?php echo h(date('d-M-y',strtotime($order['Order']['delivery_date']))); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($status[$order['Order']['status']]); ?>&nbsp; 
  </td>
  <td>
       <?php echo $this->Form->input('id', ['type'=>'hidden','value'=>$order['Order']['id']]); ?>
       <?php echo $this->Form->input('user_id', ['empty'=>'--Select--','options'=>$users, 'selected'=>$order['User']['id'], 'div' => false, 'label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control']); ?>
   </td>
   <td>
       <?php echo $this->Form->input('tailor_price', ['value' =>$order['Order']['tailor_price'], 'div' => false, 'label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control','style'=>'max-width:140px;']); ?>
   </td>
   <td>
            <?php echo $this->Form->button(__('Update'), ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) ?>          
   </td>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

your `th` and `td` are not equal `th` are 8 and `td` are only 6 
(which is why your column are mixing)

```
<table class="table table-hover ">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Customer</th>
    <th>Dress</th>
    <th>Order Date</th>
    <th>Delivery Date</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Tailor</th>
    <th>Tailor Cost</th>
    <th class="actions"><?php echo __('Actions'); ?></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($orders as $order): ?>
    <tr>
        <?php echo $this->Form->create('Order',['class'=>'form-inline']); ?>
        <td>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link($order['Customer']['name'], array('controller' => 'customers', 'action' => 'view', $order['Customer']['id'])); ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link($order['Dress']['type'], array('controller' => 'dresses', 'action' => 'view', $order['Dress']['id'])); ?>
        </td>
        <td><?php echo h(date('d-M-y',strtotime($order['Order']['order_date']))); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h(date('d-M-y',strtotime($order['Order']['delivery_date']))); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($status[$order['Order']['status']]); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('id', ['type'=>'hidden','value'=>$order['Order']['id']]); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('user_id', ['empty'=>'--Select--','options'=>$users, 'selected'=>$order['User']['id'], 'div' => false, 'label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control']); ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $this->Form->input('tailor_price', ['value' =>$order['Order']['tailor_price'], 'div' => false, 'label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control','style'=>'max-width:140px;']); ?>
        </td>   
        <td>
            <?php echo $this->Form->button(__('Update'), ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) ?>
        </td>
        <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: this is the same answer I posted above.

Comment: Answers shouldn't be code only @RiyasKpYiideveloper And despite that both answers are technically wrong, because they produce invalid HTML. The `tr` element only allows `td`, `th`, `script` and `template` elements as children. Look at it with the inspector, you'll notice that the form is closed immediately, and that the input elements are placed outside of it. This only works by chance so to speak, as soon as the browsers become a little more strict, this will stop working. **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967564/form-inside-a-table**