# express/pug loop to generate table with form per row

Tags: node.js, express, templates, pug

Im just starting out with node.js/express/pug but i cannot get it to produce a form per row.

i have this template

```
mixin listentry(alternate,name,exposureTime,manufactor,usecount,lastused)
tr()
    | <form action='' method='post'>
    td()
        input(type='text',name='name',readonly,class='w100',value=name)
    td()
        input(type='number',name='exposureTime',class='w75',value=exposureTime)
    td()
        input(type='text',name='manufactor',class='w100',value=manufactor)
    if usecount == ""
        td()
        td() never
    else
        td() #{usecount}
        td() #{lastused}
    td() Delete Update
    | </form>


- var alternate = false;
each profile,name in profiles
    +listentry(alternate,name,profile.exposureTime,profile.manufactor,profile.usecount,profile.lastused)
    - var alternate = !alternate;
```

this produces:

```
<tr>
   <form>....</form>
   <td>.... ect
```

but i expected it to make

```
<tr>
   <form.....
   <td>.... ect
   </form>
```

What am i doing wrong?

No matter what i try, i cannot get it to produce a form containing the td's of a row, hence i dont the input into the form.

I and i try dont wish to have one big form containing all the rows.

edit: new version with form() but still do not produce the desired output

```
mixin listentry(alternate,name,exposureTime,manufactor,usecount,lastused)
   tr()
     form(action='', method='post')
        td()
            input(type='text',name='name',readonly,class='w100',value=name)
        td()
            input(type='number',name='exposureTime',class='w75',value=exposureTime)
        td()
            input(type='text',name='manufactor',class='w100',value=manufactor)
        if usecount == ""
            td()
            td() never
        else
            td() #{usecount}
            td() #{lastused}
        td() Delete Update
```

Comment: Check your formatting. Right now your mixin definition is empty, since the line below it is not indented.

Comment: I have checked, and rewrote this a few times allready, and this morning i did it again, still with the same result

Comment: It is invalid html to have a `form` element immediately inside a `tr` element. Only `td` or `th` elements are allowed to be immediate children of a `tr` ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr)). Your compiler or browser may be attempting to correct this error, resulting in unexpected output.

Comment: damn, you are right, this used to work a decade ago when i did a lot of web development, it might have been a hack thou - thanks  Going to use jquery to submit a row instead - what a shame..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apperently Sean is right, you cannot have a form in per row any more.

so solution is to use jquery

[Create a HTML table where each TR is a FORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035966/create-a-html-table-where-each-tr-is-a-form/15600151#15600151)

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed easily by using standard pug elements instead of escaped HTML (with the `|`) and making sure that everything you want INSIDE the form is indented two more spaces past the form element.

```
  form(action='' method='post')
    td()
      input(type='text',name='name',readonly,class='w100',value=name)
    td()
      input(type='number',name='exposureTime',class='w75',value=exposureTime)
    td()
      input(type='text',name='manufactor',class='w100',value=manufactor)
    if usecount == ""
      td()
      td() never
    else
      td() #{usecount}
      td() #{lastused}
    td() Delete Update
```

Comment: I have checked indentation. and in fact i started with form(), but that gave me same problem so i went the with the escaped html route so see if that helped. im going to edit my original question so show this as well