# htmx: How to make each row behave like a form?

Tags: htmx

I would like to have a table like this, and make every row behave like a `<form>`.

If the user hits "Save" only the current row should get submitted to the server.

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Email</th>
  <th></th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="email"></td>
  <td><input type="submit" value="Save"></td>
 </tr> 
  <tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="email"></td>
  <td><input type="submit" value="Save"></td>
 </tr> 
  <tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="email"></td>
  <td><input type="submit" value="Save"></td>
 </tr> 
</table>
```

[image: table]

I tried `<tr hx-post="..."> ...` but this submits all input elements, not just the current row.

I played around with [hx-include](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-include/) and [hx-params](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-params/), but found not solution up to now.

Comment: Instead of hacking htmx, I could straight-forward htmx by using css: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035966/create-a-html-table-where-each-tr-is-a-form/15600151#15600151 (since I don't need colspan or rowspan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the way tables elements work, you can't really use a wrapping element here, so  you have a unique ID per row and use that to identify the inputs for the row.

You should be able to use the ID to generate a class on the inputs and then include them using the `hx-include` attribute:

```html
 <tr>
  <td><input class='row1-inputs' type="text" name="name"></td>
  <td><input class='row1-inputs' type="text" name="email"></td>
  <td><input hx-include='.row1-inputs' type="submit" value="Save"></td>
 </tr>
```