# The error of can not find View in Ajax form

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-ajax

I ask a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11372421/ajaxform-in-result-of-ajaxform)

So I add Some `OnComplete` Functions and Id to Ajax Forms, And there is:

This is My View:

```
@foreach(var item in Model) {
 <tr id="TR@(item.Id)">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("_PhoneRow", item);}
 </tr>
}
```

`_PhoneRow`:

```
@model PhoneModel
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("EditPhone", new { id = Model.Id }, new AjaxOptions {
UpdateTargetId = "TR" + Model.Id,
OnComplete = "OnCompleteEditPhone"
}, new { id = "EditAjaxForm" + Model.Id})) {
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.PhoneNumber)</td>
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.PhoneKind)</td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Edit" class="CallEditPhone" id="edit@(Model.Id)" /></td>
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult EditPhone(long Id) {
  //Get model by id
  return PartialView("_EditPhoneRow", model);
}

public ActionResult SavePhone(PhoneModel model) {
  //Save Phone, and Get Updatet model
  return PartialView("_PhoneRow", model);
}
```

`_EditPhoneRow`

```
    @model PhoneModel
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("SavePhone", new { id = Model.Id }, new AjaxOptions {
UpdateTargetId = "TR" + Model.Id,
OnComplete = "OnCompleteSavePhone"
})) {
<td>@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model.PhoneNumber)</td>
<td>@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model.PhoneKind)</td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Save" class="SaveEditPhone" id="save@(Model.Id)" /></td>
}
```

And `Oncomplete` Scripts:

```
function OnCompleteEditPhone() {

$('input.SaveEditPhone').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id").substring(4);
    $('form#SaveAjaxForm' + id).trigger('submit');
});
}

function OnCompleteSavePhone() {
$('input.CallEditPhone').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id").substring(4);
    $('form#EditAjaxForm' + id).trigger('submit');
});
}
```

So Click Edit Worked perfect, Then Click Save Worked good also, But in second time when i click the Edit Button I have an Error in Post Action I copy the Firebug console here:

```
http://Mysite/members/editphone/7652 200 OK 582ms
http://Mysite/members/savephone/7652 200 OK 73ms
http://Mysite/members/editphone/7652 500 internal server error 136ms
<title>The view 'EditPhone' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched: ...
```

So where is the problem? If I remove `OnCompleteSavePhone` The Edit button for second time not worked, and with this function I have an error that not make any sense, How Can I fix it? I actually load partial views by Ajax, And need the buttons of this views worked correctly, at first every thing is fine but after Ajax result They don't, I think to add some `Oncomplete` functions, but there is an error also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your previous question is [answered now](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11373102/29407). You had broken markup. As a consequence of this you no longer need to care about any `OnComplete` events and doing some auto triggers, form submissions and stuff. This will be handled by the `Ajax.BeginForm` infrastructure automatically for you.