# MVC3 ASP.NET Ajax BeginForm doesn't work sometimes when it's injected by other Ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, ajax.beginform

I'm trying to have some  Ajax form in the page which is not working at all, it does not send any requests on submit, noting in firebug, the form is being loaded to page by ajax, but I have other forms which are loaded to form by ajax into a jquery UI dialog and they are working fine, here is my whole partial view code , (the Part with action "SeacrhTasksTable" not working) I'd attach the rendered the whole HTML but it's so big.

```
@model APS.HelpDesk.UI.MyModel<APS.HelpDesk.Data.App_ProjectTask>
<h2>
    پروژه
    @ViewBag.ProjectTitle
</h2>
<div class="wrapperTask">
    <div class="firstTask">
   @* <input type="hidden" value="@(ViewBag.ProjectId)" />*@
        @Ajax.ActionLink("تعریف کار جدید", "AddProjectTaskDialog", new
   {
       Id = ViewBag.ProjectId,
       area = "ProjectAdmin"
   }, new AjaxOptions()
   {
       HttpMethod = "GET",
       LoadingElementId = "AddProjectTaskLoadingGif",
       UpdateTargetId = "AddProjectTaskDialog",
       InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
       OnBegin = "clearDialogs();",
       OnSuccess = " $('#AddProjectTaskDialog').dialog('open');"
   }, new { id = "AddProjecTaskLink" })
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="resetbutton">بارگذاری مجدد جدول </a>
    </div>
    <div class="secondTask">
        <div id="AddProjectTaskLoadingGif" style="display: none;">
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/ajax-loader/253L.gif")" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="test">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                #
            </th>
            <th>
                کد کار
            </th>
            <th>
                عنوان کار
            </th>
            <th style="min-width: 300px;">
                مختصری از توضيحات
            </th>
            <th>
                تاريخ ايجاد کار
            </th>
            <th>
                مهلت انجام
            </th>
            <th>
                وضعيت
            </th>
            <th>
                وابستگی های کار
            </th>
            <th colspan="2">
                ويرايش و حذف
            </th>
        </tr>
         @using (Ajax.BeginForm("SeacrhTasksTable", new { area = "ProjectAdmin" }, new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        UpdateTargetId = "test" 
    }))
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="IdTask"  style = "width:40px"  name = "Id" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="TitleTask"  style = "width:80%;" placeholder = "جست و جو" name = "Title" />
                </td>
                <td style="min-width: 250px;">
                    <input type="text" id="DescriptionTask"  style = "width:80%;" placeholder = "جست و جو" name = "Description" />
                </td>

                 <td>
                     <input type="text" id="DeliverDateTask"  style = "width:80%;" placeholder = "جست و جو" name = "DeliverDate" />
                 </td>
                 <td>
                     <input type="text" id="DeadlineDateTask"  style = "width:80%;" placeholder = "جست و جو" name = "DeadlineDate" />
                 </td>
                 <td>
                   <select name="Status">
                       <option value="0"> همه</option>
                       <option value="1">شروع نشده</option>
                       <option value="2">در حال انجام</option>
                       <option value="3">تمام شده</option>
                       <option value="4">بی مسئول</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td colspan="4">

                    <input type="submit" value="submit" style="" />
                    <input type="hidden" value="@(ViewBag.ProjectId)" name="ProjectId" id ="ProjectIdTask"/>

                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        <tbody id="TaskList">
            @Html.Partial("_ProjectTaskList", Model.MyList)
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    صفحه
                    @(Model.PageIndex + 1)
                    از
                    @Model.TotalPages
                    [ تعداد کل : @Model.TotalCount ]
                </td>
                <td id="pagesizeTaskTd" style="text-align: center;">
                    سايز صفحه
                    <select id="pagesizeTask">
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="10" selected="selected">10</option>
                        <option value="25">25</option>
                        <option value="50">50</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td colspan="6" align="left" class="tfoot-padding" id="morepagesTask">
                    @{
                        int start = Model.PageIndex;
                        if (start > 0)
                        {
                            int c = 0;
                            while (start > 0 && c < 4)
                            {
                                c++;
                                start--;
                            }
                        }
                        for (int j = start; j < Model.TotalPages && j < start + 10; j++)
                        {
                            if (Model.PageIndex != j)
                            {


                        <span>
                            @Ajax.ActionLink((j + 1).ToString(), "TaskListTablePage", "Project", new
                       {
                           Id = ViewBag.ProjectId,
                           PageIndex = j,
                           PageSize = Model.PageSize,
                           area = "ProjectAdmin"
                       }, new AjaxOptions
                       {
                           HttpMethod = "GET",
                           UpdateTargetId = "test",
                           InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
                       }, new { mode = "mode" })
                        </span>
                            }
                            else
                            { 
                        <span><b style="text-decoration: underline;">@(j + 1)</b></span>
                        <input type="hidden" id="PIndexAll" value="@(j)" />
                            }
                        }
                        if (Model.PageIndex + 10 < Model.TotalPages)
                        { 
                        <span>. . . </span>
                        }
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="AddProjectTaskDialog" title="تعریف کار جدید" style="text-align: right;">
</div>
<div id="EditProjectTaskDialog" title="ويرايش کار" style="text-align: right;">
</div>
<div id="ReportProjectTaskDialog" title="گزارش کل کار" style="text-align: right;">
</div>
<div id="DescriptionProjectTaskDialog" title="توضيح کار" style="text-align: right;">
</div>
<div id="EditProjectDepenDialog" style="text-align: right;">
</div>
<div id="Taskresult">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#AddProjectTaskDialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 720,
        modal: true,
        draggable: true,
        position: "top"
    });

    $("#EditProjectTaskDialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 720,
        modal: true,
        draggable: true,
        position: "top"
    });

    $("#EditProjectDepenDialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 720,
        modal: true,
        draggable: true,
        position: "top",
        buttons: {
            "OK": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });


    $("#AddProjecTaskLink").button();
    $("#resetbutton").button();


    $("#pagesizeTask").live( 'change' ,  function (){

        var val = $(this).find(":selected").val();
        $("#morepagesTask").find('*[mode]').each(function(index){

            var n=$(this).attr("href").lastIndexOf("=");
            var t= $(this).attr("href").substring(0,n+1);
            $(this).attr("href" ,t+val );
        });

          var url = '@Url.Action("TaskListTablePage", new { area = "ProjectAdmin" })';
          url += '?Id=' + @(ViewBag.ProjectId);         
          url += '&PageIndex=' + $("#PIndexAll").val();
          url += '&PageSize=' +val;         
          $.ajax({
              url: url, type: 'get',
              success: function (data, status) {
                $("#test").html('');
                $("#test").html(data);
              }
          });         

    });

     $(".firstTask").delegate( '#resetbutton','click',function(){

        var url = '@Url.Action("TaskListTablePage", new { area = "ProjectAdmin" })';
          url += '?Id=' + @(ViewBag.ProjectId);         
          url += '&PageIndex=0' ;
          url += '&PageSize=10';          

          $.ajax({
              url: url, type: 'get',
              success: function (data, status) {
                $("#test").html('');
                $("#test" ).html(data);
              }
          }); 

        });
</script>
```

HTML of Form

```
<form action="/ProjectAdmin/Project/SeacrhTasksTable" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#test" id="form0" method="post">            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="IdTask"  style = "width:40px"  name = "Id" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="TitleTask"  style = "width:80%;" placeholder = "جست و جو" name = "Title" />
                </td>
                <td style="min-width: 250px;">
                    <input type="text" id="DescriptionTask"  style = "width:80%;" placeholder = "جست و جو" name = "Description" />
                </td>

                 <td>
                     <input type="text" id="DeliverDateTask"  style = "width:80%;" placeholder = "جست و جو" name = "DeliverDate" />
                 </td>
                 <td>
                     <input type="text" id="DeadlineDateTask"  style = "width:80%;" placeholder = "جست و جو" name = "DeadlineDate" />
                 </td>
                 <td>
                   <select name="Status">
                       <option value="0"> همه</option>
                       <option value="1">شروع نشده</option>
                       <option value="2">در حال انجام</option>
                       <option value="3">تمام شده</option>
                       <option value="4">بی مسئول</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td colspan="4">

                    <input type="submit" value="submit" style="" />
                    <input type="hidden" value="38" name="ProjectId" id ="ProjectIdTask"/>

                </td>
            </tr>
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you have invalid markup. By invalid markup I mean that you have a `<form>` nested directly inside a `<tr>` which is forbidden by the specification. You cannot have a `<form>` inside a `<table>`, `<tbody>` or `<tr>`.

To illustrate the problem in a simplified manner, here's what you have currently which is invalid:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <form>
            <td>Foo</td>
            <td>Bar</td>
            <td><input type="submit" /></td>
        </form>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Just inspect the DOM with FireBug and you will see how your `<form>` is floating alone (opening and closing immediately) without any elements inside.

This is invalid markup and it results in undefined behavior which in your case translates by the browser simply not submitting the form. The reason this happens is because the `unobtrusive-ajax` library that you are using subscribes to the submit event to all ajax forms using a `.live`:

```
$("form[data-ajax=true]").live("submit", function (evt) {
    ...
});
```

The thing is that the submit event is never raised in this case. A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11372421/29407) has been asked yesterday with the same problem.

To fix this problem you could use nested tables:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Foo</td>
                        <td>Bar</td>
                        <td><input type="submit" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So simply put your `Ajax.BeginForm` inside a `<td>` and then use a nested table to put the elements.