# jQuery AJAX Formatting - HTML PHP form formatting auto changed after loaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to make a AJAX code with PHP.

Main PHP code is [here](http://www.codeshare.io/vqnA8).

And supporting PHP code (which load with AJAX every time) is [here](http://www.codeshare.io/jlOXV).

AJAX is loaded perfectly.

But it is not loaded perfectly.

What AJAX is supposed to do is giving this type of code every time -

```
                <tr>
                    <form action="update" method="post">
                        <th nowrap=""><?php echo '<a href="profile/'.$row_list['vanity_url'].'" target="_new">'.substr($row_list['name'],0,15).'</a>'; ?></th>
                        <th ><input type="text" readonly value='<?php echo $row_list['vanity_url']; ?>' class="login-text name right10 form-control" style="width: 600px" id="registerCompany" name="old"></th>
                        <th nowrap=""><br/></th>
                        <th ><input type="text" class="login-text name right10 form-control" style="width: 600px" id="registerCompany" name="new" placeholder="*New URL" required autocomplete="off" ></th>
                        <th nowrap=""><br/></th>
                        <th nowrap=""><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button></th>
                    </form>
                </tr>
```

But it is not giving this. It is giving

```
                 <tr>
                    <form action="update" method="post"></form>
                        <th nowrap=""><?php echo '<a href="profile/'.$row_list['vanity_url'].'" target="_new">'.substr($row_list['name'],0,15).'</a>'; ?></th>
                        <th ><input type="text" readonly value='<?php echo $row_list['vanity_url']; ?>' class="login-text name right10 form-control" style="width: 600px" id="registerCompany" name="old"></th>
                        <th nowrap=""><br/></th>
                        <th ><input type="text" class="login-text name right10 form-control" style="width: 600px" id="registerCompany" name="new" placeholder="*New URL" required autocomplete="off" ></th>
                        <th nowrap=""><br/></th>
                        <th nowrap=""><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button></th>
                </tr>
```

So, the form is closed, so it can't be used.

Can anyone help me, please?

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: Your returned HTML is not valid.

check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249688/html-is-it-possible-to-have-a-form-tag-in-each-table-row-in-a-xhtml-valid-way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this code

```
while($row_list=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        { ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form action="update" method="post">
                        <table style="width:100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td nowrap="">  <?php echo '<a href="profile/'.$row_list['vanity_url'].'" target="_new">'.substr($row_list['name'],0,15).'</a>'; ?> </td>
                                <td>            <input type="text" readonly value='<?php echo $row_list['vanity_url']; ?>' class="login-text name right10 form-control" style="width: 600px" id="registerCompany" name="old">   </td>
                                <td>            <input type="text" class="login-text name right10 form-control" style="width: 600px" id="registerCompany" name="new" placeholder="*New URL" required autocomplete="off" >   </td>       
                                <td nowrap="">  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>       </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
<?php   }
```

Think it will be solved.