# Can't find form after injecting it with jQuery(I think)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im adding the form, in an on-click event, to a row in a table using (Sorry about the really long row):

```
$('#row'+rowvalues[0]).html('
    <form id="updform'+rowvalues[0]+'">
    <td>'+rowvalues[0]+'</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="namn'+rowvalues[0]+'" value="'+rowvalues[1]+'">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="ingred'+rowvalues[0]+'" value="'+rowvalues[2]+'">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="number" name="pris'+rowvalues[0]+'" value="'+rowvalues[3]+'">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="number" name="fampris'+rowvalues[0]+'" value="'+rowvalues[4]+'">
    </td>
    <td>
        <Button class="upddatasave" id="sub'+rowvalues[0]+'">Submit</button>
    </form>
</td>
');
intialiseUpdatebutton();
```

then I initialize the button using the fuction called intialiseUpdatebutton();

that function looks like:

```
 function intialiseUpdatebutton() {
    $(".upddatasave").on("click", function() {
        var butid = $(this).attr('id');
        var dataid = parseInt(butid.slice(3));
        console.log(dataid);
        console.log($('#namn'+dataid).val());
        var formvalues = $('#updform'+dataid).serializeArray();
        console.log(formvalues);
     });
}
```

It finds the button and it works, but I can't find the form. My guess was that it cant find the injected form, but if that's the case how do I fix it? like I do with the initialise function for the button.

What Im trying to do: Im displaying data from an SQL table in a table in html - It has 2 buttons 1 update and 1 delete. Im trying to fix the update button so that when I press it the cells with the values change into a form with textfields and the values in there and then you can just change the values and press submit to save the changes.

Edit: jsfiddle.net/rh8deo79/2 <- jsfiddle

Comment: Why are you _"initializing"_ the button? this `$(".upddatasave").on("click", function() {...});` means that whenever someone click on it, the function will be executed, but because you put it inside a function it may not be able to reach it... try taking it out of the function and don't worry, jquery takes care of linking the event, if that is why you _"initialize"_ it

Comment: The DOM you are trying to generate is invalid. A `<td>` cannot be a child element of a `<form>`.

Comment: ah, you might be correct - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249688/html-is-it-possible-to-have-a-form-tag-in-each-table-row-in-a-xhtml-valid-way . Thanks for the help. Ill try to change everything to divs instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By editing your formmatting job to break up the massive one-liner, I found that you end your `<form>` before your `<td>`, which is invalid html and probably your source of error.

Comment: hmm, tried it. Didnt work. Sorry about the one-liner I tried with doing it with + signs and breaking rows couldnt get it to work then - must've dont something wrong. Ty for the reply though

Comment: Can you set up a js fiddle with a sample for rowvalues?

Comment: I'm seeing the `form` get terminated before the first `td`, so that the inputs are not enclosed in it (at least in Chrome 49). Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rh8deo79/

Comment: I'll try making a jsfiddle, never done it before but gimme a sec

Comment: I updated your js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rh8deo79/1/. You can now find the form if you use chrome and rightclick->inspect an element in the result.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rh8deo79/2/ <- here's one with pretty much exactly the code I have that's relevant I think.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249688/html-is-it-possible-to-have-a-form-tag-in-each-table-row-in-a-xhtml-valid-way <- think this might be the issue

Comment: It could be, and it is probably a better idea to have the form outside of the `<tr>`, since it isn't wrapping your `<td>`'s anyway.

Comment: You could just have one form though, and update what it's action is based on what button you press. The one form would wrap the whole table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reorganize your tags. You can't have `<tr><form><td>`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967564/form-inside-a-table).

You might try creating a new table inside each form.