# Dynamically created DOM elements on ajax success method

Tags: ajax, dom

i have a little error with my ajax success method DOM elements creation. on the success method i have created an html table row and inside that row i have created a form but this form not work ass expected.

this is a code on ajax success

```
success: function(data) {   
        
        html='';
        for (i = 0; i < data['qoutations'].length; i++) {
            html+='<tr><form method="post" action="index.php?route=catalog/product/getForm&user_token={{ user_token }}">';
            html+='<td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="'+data['qoutations'][i]['qoutation_id']+'" /></td>';
                
            html+='<td class="text-left">'+data['qoutations'][i]['customer_id'];
            html+='<input type="hidden" id="customer_id" value="'+data['qoutations'][i]['qoutation_id']+'"/></td>';
            html+='<td class="text-left">'+data['qoutations'][i]['description']+'</td>';                    
            html+='<td class="text-left"> <div class="form-group">';
            html+='<textarea class="form-control" rows="2" id="qouted"></textarea>';
            html+='</div></td>';

            html+='<td class="text-left">';
            var customer_id1=data['qoutations'][i]['customer_id'];
            var qoutation_id1=data['qoutations'][i]['qoutation_id'];                                
            html+='<input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" id="createproduct" value="Create Product" onClick="createProduct(\'' + customer_id1 + '\',\''+qoutation_id1+'\')"/></td>';
            
            html+='<td class="text-left">'+data['qoutations'][i]['qouted']+'</td>';
            html+='<td class="text-left">'+data['qoutations'][i]['status']+'</td>';
            
            html+='<td class="text-left">'+data['qoutations'][i]['date'];
            html+='<input type="hidden" id="date" value="'+data['qoutations'][i]['date']+'"/></td>';
            
            html+='<td class="text-left">';
            html+='<input class="btn btn-danger" type="button" id="cancel" value="cancel"/></td>';
            html+='</tr>';
        }
        $('#detail').html(html);
}
```

and this picture elaborate my error. as this picture shows form element open and close immediately.
[DOM screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzdI3.png)

please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you are actually not following the standard to create html in your ajax callback. 
You can't have a form inside a table row. Only way to do this is to divide your table row into sub form. Please take a look at this question.
[HTML: Is it possible to have a FORM tag in each TABLE ROW in a XHTML valid way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249688/html-is-it-possible-to-have-a-form-tag-in-each-table-row-in-a-xhtml-valid-way)